# Passing props from grandchildren to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I have following React.js application structure:

```
<App />
  <BreadcrumbList>
    <BreadcrumbItem />
  <BreadcrumbList/>
<App />
```

The problem is, when I click on `<BreadcrumbItem />` , I want to change a state in `<App />`

I used callback to pass props to `<BreadcrumbList/>` but that`s how far I got.
Is there any pattaren how to easily pass props up to compenent tree ?

How can I pass prop to `<App />`, without doing any callback chaining ?

Comment: I can recomend you **[This](https://www.tildedave.com/2014/11/15/introduction-to-contexts-in-react-js.html)** link rly good explanation about your problem

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are doing something simple then its often just better to pass the change in state up through the component hierarchy rather than create a store specifically for that purpose (whatever it may be). I would do the following:

BreadcrumbItem

```
var React = require('react/addons');
var BreadcrumbItem = React.createClass({

embiggenMenu: function() {
    this.props.embiggenToggle();
},

render: function() {
    return (
            <div id="embiggen-sidemenu" onClick={this.embiggenMenu} />
    );
}
});

module.exports = BreadcrumbItem ;
```

THEN pass it up to the parent through the BreadcrumbList component.....

```
 <BreadcrumbItem embiggenToggle={this.props.embiggenToggle}>
```

... and UP to App, then use it to set the state....

```
var React = require('react/addons');

var App = React.createClass({

embiggenMenu: function() {
    this.setState({
        menuBig: !this.state.menuBig
    });
},

render: function() {
    return (

        <div>

            <BreadcrumbList embiggenToggle={this.embiggenMenu} />

        </div>

        )
    }
});
module.exports = BreadcrumbItem;
```

This example toggles a simple boolean however you can pass up anything you like. I hope this helps.

I have not tested this but it was (quickly) ripped from a live working example.

---

EDIT:
As it was requested i'll expand upon the vague: "you can pass up anything".

If you were making a navigation menu based on an array and needed to pass up the selected item to a parent then you would do the following

```
var React = require('react/addons');

var ChildMenu = React.createClass({


getDefaultProps: function () {
    return {
        widgets : [
            ["MenuItem1"],
            ["MenuItem2"],
            ["MenuItem3"],
            ["MenuItem4"],
            ["MenuItem5"],
            ["MenuItem6"],
            ["MenuItem7"]
        ]
    }
},

handleClick: function(i) {
    console.log('You clicked: ' + this.props.widgets[i]);
    this.props.onClick(this.props.widgets[i]);
},

render: function() {
    return (
        <nav>
            <ul>
                {this.props.widgets.map(function(item, i) {
                    var Label = item[0];

                    return (
                        <li
                            onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, i)}
                            key={i}>

                            {Label}
                        </li>
                    );
                }, this)}
            </ul>
        </nav>
    );
}
});

module.exports = ChildMenu;
```

You would then do the following in the parent:

```
var React = require('react/addons');

var ChildMenuBar = require('./app/top-bar.jsx');

var ParentApp = React.createClass({

widgetSelectedClick: function(selection) {
    //LOGGING
    //console.log('THE APP LOGS: ' + selection);

    //VARIABLE SETTING
    var widgetName = selection[0];

    //YOU CAN THEN USE THIS "selection"
    //THIS SETS THE APP STATE
    this.setState({
        currentWidget: widgetName
    });
},

render: function() {
        return (
                <ChildMenu onClick={this.widgetSelectedClick} />
        );
    }
});

module.exports = ParentApp;
```

I hope this helps. Thanks for the upvote.

Comment: if this comment is useful please upvote, Im working on increasing my SO rep and any help or feedback would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Can you explaing how to pass a value, for example an id, of clicked breadcrumbitem ?

Comment: UPDATE: Its also worth adding that, when you are at the point where you are passing things up and down your component tree thats usually the point to start considering a state container, Redux being the most commonly used with react at the time of writing.

Comment: UPDATE 2: Its worth Pointing out this has been answered more comprehensively and recently here (both ES6 and createClass based examples):
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs

Answer (score 2):

If you use Flux pattern, you can have a **AppStore** which listen a **BREADCRUMB_CLICK** event. So when you click on a BreadCrumbItem, you can execute an action which dispatch **BREADCRUMB_CLICK** event. When **AppStore** handle the event, he inform **App** component which update your state.

For more informations:

[Flux architecture](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#content)