# pass value from child to parent component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have component A and B. Component A pass state as prop to component, says it's named show

so in my component B's render function it will be like this

```
{this.props.show &&
   <div>popup content</div>
}
```

But how I close it now? I have to pass a flag from component B to the parent? as I know it react you can pass stuff back to parent.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Comment: found a nice article about communication between react components https://www.ctheu.com/2015/02/12/how-to-communicate-between-react-components/#children-to-parent

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to pass data from a child to a parent, the parent needs to pass a function capable of handling that data to the child.

```
var Parent = React.createClass({

    getData: function(data){
         this.setState({childData: data});     
    }

    render: function(){
        return(
            <Child sendData={this.getData} />
        );
    }

});

var Child = React.createClass({

    textChange: function(event){
        this.setState({textString: event.target.value});
    }

    buttonClick: function(){
        this.props.sendData(this.state.textString);
    }

    render: function(){
        <div>
        <input type="text" value={this.state.textString} 
               onChange={this.textChange}/>
        <button onClick={this.buttonClick}
        </div>
    }

});
```

There are other ways of handling data, and it might be worth your while creating a data store to store global variables and handle various events. In this way you would keep the data flow of your application one way. In smaller scale cases however, this solution should suffice.

Comment: global variable u means using redux? or it's doable without redux?

Comment: I believe I used Reflux in my personal experience.

Comment: @boyde712 in your parent function you should do <Child sendData={this.getData} />, because if you send this.props.getData, you'll get an error in your console, saying that sendData is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Use the eventBus to send/receive date from child/parent components respectively.

Example below:

```
class Date extends Component {

 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        date:'',           
}
   this.callback = this.callback.bind(this); // register callback method
}

callback(date){    // callback method to receive data
    this.setState({date: date});
}


componentDidMount(){
    EventBus.on("date", this.callback);
}
render() {

<div>
      {this.state.date}
</div>
  }
}
```

From any other component

```
 handleDayClick(day) {
         EventBus.publish("date", day);
  }
```

https://github.com/arkency/event-bus

Comment: It's a bad pattern, hard to debug when your app grows.

Comment: Now there is really good debug tools builtin in chrome for debug react component. You shouldn't have any problem.