# How can I set the state of my parent component from the child component when using react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working on a React project where the user will be prompted a series of questions, the answers to which will be combined as an object to be saved.

The parent component contains several children.

for example--

```html
<Route path="Parent" component={Parent}>
    <Route path="Child1" component={Child1} />
    <Route path="Child2" component={Child2} />
    <Route path="Child3" component={Child3} />
    <IndexRoute component={Child1} />
</Route>
```

The parent will have an initial state of empty values 
ex. (this.state={value1:"", value2:""})

How can I pass data from the child to the parent (and props from the parent to the children) when using {this.props.children}?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `component` prop to render your child routes, use the `render` prop. This allows you to have a function return the component that you want to render, instead of simply accepting the class itself. It looks like this:

```
<Route path="Parent" component={Parent}>
    <Route path="Child1" render={() => {<Child1 someProp={foo} />}} />
    <Route path="Child2" render={() => {<Child2 someProp={bar} />}} />
    <Route path="Child3" render={() => {<Child3 someProp={baz} />}} />
    <IndexRoute component={Child1} />
</Route>
```

Why do it this way instead? Well, as you can see, now you can pass props to the rendered children (in this example, `someProp`). And now that you can pass props to children, it is trivial to [use callbacks to modify parent state from the children.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917854/pass-value-from-child-to-parent-component-in-react)

[More info on the `render` prop here.](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)

Comment: Great. Please, also consider to don't use the `state` at all and move the implementation to a `StateManager` such as `Redux`.

Comment: For react router v4, this is a preferred way of doing so, just be sure to use render instead of component to avoid additional mounting and re-rendering.

Answer (score 1):

In order for a parent to get data from its child back, you need to pass a callback function as a property to that child.

```
callbackFunction(data) {
    // do something
}

<ChildComponent parentCallback={this.callbackFunction} />
```

Then you can use the prop inside the child component to send data back to its parent, which will then use the callback function to do something with it.

```
const x = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
this.props.parentCallback(x);
```

Check the following article for more details: https://medium.com/@ruthmpardee/passing-data-between-react-components-103ad82ebd17

Another option is to use a state container like Redux. In this scenario your child component would dispatch the value to a state, and this state is being listened to by its parent, which will re-render when state changes. This is a solution for more complex scenarios