# this.props.filterUser is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to pass data from chid to parent but
I've been thrown below exception
this.props.filterUser is not a function

I am referencing: 
[ReactJS with ES6: this.props is not a function when I communicate two components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31141444/reactjs-with-es6-this-props-is-not-a-function-when-i-communicate-two-components)

Uncaught TypeError: this.props.filterUser is not a function

```
class Mobile extends React.Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.legendBtnHandler = this.legendBtnHandler.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            mobileExtentions: '',
            legendInfo: '',
            buttonName: 'test'
        }
    };

 componentWillMount(){
        const listItems = mobileExt.map((ext) =>
            <p>
                <RaisedButton label={ext.name} secondary={true} id="mobileBtn" onClick={() => this.legendBtnHandler(ext.name)}/>
            </p>
        );

        this.setState({mobileExtentions: listItems});
    };


    legendBtnHandler(btnName){
        this.setState({buttonName: btnName});
        Store.buttonName = btnName;
        this.props.filterUser("test");
    };


    render(){
        const dragHandlers = {onStart: this.onStart, onStop: this.onStop};
        return(
            <div>
               <DraggableCard
                   mobileExtentions = { this.state.mobileExtentions }
                   legendInfo = { mobileExt[0].legendInfo }
               />
            </div>
        )
    }
};
```

Parent

```
class MapClass extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.filterUser = this.filterUser.bind(this);

            this.state =  {
                filter: ''
                //btnName: Legend.props.test
            }

        }

     filterUser(filterValue){
            alert(filterValue)
            this.setState({
                filter: filterValue
            });
        }

    render(){
        return(
           <Mobile filterUser={this.filterUser}/>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: If you try to pass something else like here
  `<Mobile filterUser={this.filterUser} smthElse={[1,2,3]}/>` could you tell what the output if you check it int your `componentWillMount()` functon, like just adding `console.log(this.props)`?

Comment: Could it be because he is not passing `props` to `super` on `Mobile` component?

Comment: @bennygenel, nope, as Shubham Khatri (thank you, btw) mentioned https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30571875/whats-the-difference-between-super-and-superprops-in-react-when-using-e

Comment: <Mobile filterUser={this.filterUser} smthElse={[1,2,3]}/> doesn't work, still throws "Uncaught TypeError: this.props.filterUser is not a function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for your kind reply.
However the problem was that, I was calling the Mobile class in Navigation class (as well) and I haven't implement the filter function in Navigation.

reference:
[pass value from child to parent component in react](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42917854/pass-value-from-child-to-parent-component-in-react#comment79899942_42918362)

Matej Marić's comment was very useful

Answer (score 0):

Try the **arrow syntax** of a function, it will give you access to the right context

like `legendBtnHandler = btnName => this.props.filterUser("test");`

Comment: but he using the bind here  `this.legendBtnHandler = this.legendBtnHandler.bind(this);`, shouldn't it be solving this kind of problem (with `this`)?

Comment: Being trying to reproduce it like that https://i.imgur.com/KDhBZrf.png, but as you can see it sees the function in props. But, yes, I can mistaken too as well, because of `this.props` has the function it should in any case, I mean, without calling it inside `someInnerF`

Comment: Yeah, you right, but we need more details about architecture of the app, to understand what's wrong.

Comment: Oh, btw, there is `react-native` tag. Could it be something related to mobile platforms specific?

Comment: Maybe. But looks like usual React class.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply :( here's what I want to do: I want to pass Mobile class's RaisedButton onclick event to be listened by MapClass. I'm calling Mobile class from the navigation class. I've been try to achieve this in many other ways including refs, but that didn't work because of the dynamic behaviour of the button

Comment: legendBtnHandler = btnName => this.props.filterUser("test"); didn't work either :( throws Uncaught TypeError: _this2.props.filterUser is not a function