# How to show only values of multi selected items using react-select?

Tags: reactjs, select

```js
handleBeaconChange = (beacons) => {
          this.setState({
              beacons
          });

      };
```

```js
 this.state = {
            name: '',
            color: [],
            description: '',
            beacons: []
        };
```

```js
                         <Select.Async 
                          multi={true} 
                          className="margin-select"
                          value={this.state.beacons}
                          loadOptions={getBeacons}
                          onChange={this.handleBeaconChange}/>
```

[image][![This is the problem I'm facing actually
I had used react-select and using that I'm using multi-select functionality.

Now the Problem is I can select multiple items but it's showing the complete object in the array rather than only the values.
When I used simpleValue attribute it passes only value but not as a kind of element in an array but as a string separated by ",(comma)" than other string
What I want is the value of all the items selected in an array][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oWwA.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oWwA.png)

Comment: Could you share the actual array,selected array and current output ?

Comment: beacons[] is an array in the code

Comment: If I am not wrong , you are getting Name updated,1234 ,if you select beacons?

Comment: are you looking for something like this - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NjwWqo?editors=1111

Comment: getting only values instead of complete array

Comment: the box next to beacon is getting extended when you select multiple values .. is there a way to fix it and keep the box as fixed width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve expected result of getting array values use below option

```
var obj = this.state.beacons;
var x = obj.map(function(k,v){
  return v
})
console.log(x)
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/NjwWqo?editors=1111

Comment: Yes but you can see my pi i provided its retirning object (label and value), i wanted only its value

Comment: if you use map function as mentioned in codepen , you can extract values in array from the output object

Comment: thanks it worked but to how to access that variable "x" outside that function