# Reactjs pass children value to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react and was wondering what's the best way to pass a value from children to parent? Here are my components.

TodoItems -> should pass the value of the button to parent so I can remove the item from state.

```
var TodoItems = createClass ({
render:function(){

    var listItem = this.props.items.map((item) =>{
        return <li key={item.key}> {item.text} <button  onClick={this.props.removeItem} value={item.key}> x </button></li> 
    });
    return  <ul>
                {listItem} 
            </ul>
}
});
```

This is my `Body` component

```
var Body = createClass ({
 displayName: 'Body',
 getInitialState:function(){
    return {
        items: [
            {
                text:"Buy Fish",
                key: "1"
            },
            {
                text:"Learn React",
                key: "2"    
            },{
                text:"Buy new shoes",
                key:"3"
            }]
        }
 },
 addItem(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var item = this.refs.taskItem;
    var taskItem = this.state.items;
    taskItem.push({text:item.value, key:Date.now()});
    this.setState(taskItem);    
 },
 removeItem:function(e){
    console.log(1);
 },
    render:function(){
        return <div className="body"> 
            <form onSubmit={this.addItem}>
                <input ref="taskItem" />
                <button type="submit"> Add Item </button> 
            </form>
            <TodoItems removeItem={this.removeItem} {...this.props} items = {this.state.items} />
         </div>
    }
});
```

Now `Body` should get the key value of the list so I can remove it from state, what is the best React way of doing it? I'm not using any architecture at the moment.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well let's saying you're using the item's key as an identifier for removal, in the child you'd have this:

```
var TodoItems = createClass ({
render:function(){

    var listItem = this.props.items.map((item) =>{
        return <li key={item.key}> {item.text} <button  onClick={() => this.props.removeItem(item.key)} value={item.key}> x </button></li> 
    });
    return  <ul>
                {listItem} 
            </ul>
}
});
```

And then in the parent:

```
removeItem:function(key){
    this.setState({
        items: this.state.items.filter(( obj )=> {
            return obj.key !== key;
        });
    });
}
```

So in the child you're calling the property function with that item's key as an argument, then in the parent function you're removing all items with that key from the state items array (this uses ES6 as you can see)

In React you shouldn't mutate the state directly, but don't worry that set state call doesn't since `filter` returns a new array

Comment: Thank you for your answer and explanation, this makes sense. So there is nothing wrong in using `filter` ?

Comment: Nope, filter is perfectly fine :) just make sure you use something like Babel to transpile it into nice plain javascript so it's compatible with older browsers

Answer (score 1):

In your TodoItems, instead of set `removeItem` directly to `onClick`, you can call it with the item key inside an inline function which assigned to `onClick`.

```
return <li key={item.key}> {item.text} <button  onClick={()=>this.props.removeItem(item.key)} value={item.key}> x </button></li>
```