# Change style in react child componnet from event in parent componnet

Tags: reactjs

I have a react component wihch contains two child components, In the parent component i have a button that launches a function to change style in both the parent and the child.
I managed to change the style in the parent but not in the child
here's what i've done

```
var XBlockButtons = React.createClass({

getInitialState(){

return{
  Componentstyle:{display:"block"},
  HTMLstyle:{display:"none"},
}

},

showhtml(){
this.setState({
    Componentstyle:{display:"none"},
    HTMLstyle:{display:"block"}

})
},


render: function() {


var style={display:'block'}

return (


  <div className="add-xblock-component new-component-item adding">

    <div className="new-component" style={this.state.Componentstyle}>
      <ul className="new-component-type" >

        <li>

            <button type="button" className="multiple-templates add-xblock-component-button" data-type="html" onClick={this.showhtml}>
              <span className="large-template-icon large-html-icon"></span>
              <span className="sr"> Add Component:</span>
              <span className="name">HTML</span>
            </button>

        </li> /ul></div>
      <HTML/>
```

**-----Child-----**

```
var HTML = React.createClass({
render:function(){

    return(
      <div className="new-component-templates new-component-html" style={this.state.HTMLstyle}></div>);})};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass on the style as prop to the child component and then use it there like

Parent:

```
 <HTML HTMLstyle={this.state.HTMLstyle}/>
```

Now in  child

```
var HTML = React.createClass({
componentWillMount: function(){
     this.setState({HTMLstyle: this.props.HTMLstyle})
},
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
      this.setState({HTMLstyle: nextProps.HTMLstyle})
},
render:function(){

    return(
      <div className="new-component-templates new-component-html" style={this.state.HTMLstyle}></div>
    );
  }
)};
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's working great, however i couldn't understand why componentWillMount and componentWiilReceivePropos are used

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is called everytime the parent component renders and not at the first time when the child component renders, so for the first render we use componentWillMount and for any further renders we use componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: One more question, if i had to reverse the process, if i have to pass style from child to parent what do i need to change ?

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs/38397755#38397755 for the reverse method

Answer (score 0):

That's because you need to pass in the style values as props to the child component as well

```
<HTML {...HTMLstyle}/>
```

I might be wrong on the syntax but you get the idea, I hope.