# Change parent component state from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know that the question with this title has already been asked few times before but the problem is that I couldn't get an appropriate answer. So as I am new to `reactJS` and trying to create login logout form.

What I want to do is to pass or change a state of parent component from a child component through an event handler(*When a user clicks on logout button*). Below are the two Components:

**First One:**

```
class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {login : false};
    }

    login(){
       // this method updates the login.state : true
    }


    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.login ? (<ChatBox userNick="fad" />) : (<LoginScreen onSubmit={this.login} />) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

**And Second:**

```
class ChatBox extends React.Component{
    logout(){
        // Expecting or trying to update parent.state.login : false
        // via this method as well
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="chat-box">
                <button onClick={this.logout} > Logout </button>
                <h3>Hi, {this.props.userNick} </h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I have simplified these component to come on point.

**What's going here?**
`Home` Component is the main parent component. Initially the `state.login` is `false` and in this situation `LoginScreen` Components shows up. Now, when user login through `LoginScreen` Component `state.login` updates to `true`, it's time to show for `ChatBox` Component.

Now you can see that `ChatBox` Component contains a button which calls a method `logout` to logout user. **What I want** is to update once again the `state.login` to `false` in `Home` Component When user click on the *Logout Button*.

I don't know how to do it, It will be appreciate if you help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: add a ref to the `<Chatbox/>` component and access its state by using `this.refs[ChatBoxRef].state`

Comment: I don't understand ref please can you explain it in the answer?

Comment: Oh no no you should not do that. What you can do however is provide a handler to `<ChatBox>` from `<Home>` (just like what you did for `<LoginScreen>`, except to set `state.login` to `false` instead of `true`) and let `<Home>` update its state by itself.

Comment: The ref is used to return a reference to your element. You can read more here: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: @Raymond I am sorry, but this looks like very bad idea. I am not even sure it is possible to access the state from the outside, but if that is, that is very bad practice. What you are suggesting would not even trigger re-rendering anyway because you are never supposed to update the state directly but use `setState` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Comment: And as far as I remember ref is for DOM elements, not for React elements.

Comment: @QuentinRoy Hi, he can use that to access the child component's state and update the parent's state with `this.setState({})`

Comment: @QuentinRoy, for example: `this.setState({someCounter: this.refs[child].state.anotherCounter})`

Comment: @Raymond it will be good if you explain it to me in answer. I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: I fail to see how that would help OP as you still need to trigger this at some point, and the trigger comes from the child, not the parent. It seems to me there is way easier way to fetch information from children (i.e. handlers which is the recommended way). I would strongly recommend against relying on such mechanisms. And anyway, again, ref gives you the root DOM element. E.g. a <div> or <span>. You won't hack your way into a component state this way.

Comment: @QuentinRoy, you can get the child component's state using refs. I do not know if it wasn't possible in previous versions of react, but, it is now. When you assign the ref as `<Child ref={el => this.ref = el} />` and log it, you will get its props, context, refs, updater, and state. BUT, I do agree that it's not preferrable to use refs for everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it in the same way as you are doing for Login, pass a function as a prop and call it on logout, see updates below.

```js
const LoginScreen = () => (<div>Login Screen</div>);

class Home extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {login : true};
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    }

    login(){
       // this method updates the login.state : true
    }

    logout() {
       // this method updates the login.state : false
       this.setState({ login: false });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.login ? (<ChatBox userNick="fad" onLogout={this.logout} />) : (<LoginScreen onSubmit={this.login} />) }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

class ChatBox extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        // This makes sure `this` keeps pointing on this instance when logout is called from the outside.
        this.logout = this.logout.bind(this);
    }

    logout(){
        // Call the onLogout property.
        this.props.onLogout();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="chat-box">
                <button onClick={this.logout} > Logout </button>
                <h3>Hi, {this.props.userNick} </h3>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home />, document.querySelector('#main'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="main"></div>
```

Comment: This is the exact same thing you are doing for the `<Login>` component. `<Home>` provides `<ChatBox>` with a callback using on the `onLogout` property. Upon call of this callback, `Home#logout` is executed. `<Chatbox>` then call this callback (`this.props.onLogout()`) on reception of the click event on its `<button>`.

Comment: Please can you explain `onLogout` what is it's purpose and you are implementing this? thank you

Comment: There is a bug, here. `this.props.logout()` should be `this.props.onLogout()`. Let me fix it.

Comment: So means of prop `onLogout` that it is a function which calling another function?

Comment: Ok I created a running snipped and also fixed another bug about `ChatBox#logout` being unbound when passed to its button. onLogout is a property of `<ChatBox>` that happens to be given as a function. Then yeah, that function is called by a function and will then call other functions and so on.

Comment: button.onClick > ChatBox#logout > ChatBox#props.onLogout > Home#logout > Home#setState

Comment: Yeaahhhhhh...... At last that's worked... Thank youuuuuu veryy muchhhhh....

Answer (score 1):

You can pass an event from the `Parent` component to the `Child` component that handles the change of the state, like so:

```
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { isLoggedIn: false };
  }

  _handleLogin() {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true });
  }

  _handleLogout() {
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
  }

  render() {
    const { isLoggedIn } = this.state;

    return (
        <div>
       {
            isLoggedIn ?
            <ChatBox logoutEvent={this._handleLogout.bind(this)} />
          :
          <Login loginEvent={this._handleLogin.bind(this)} />
       }
        </div>
    );
  }
}

const Login = ({ loginEvent }) => (
    <button type="button" onClick={loginEvent}>Login</button>
);

const ChatBox = ({ logoutEvent }) => (
    <div>  
    <h1>This is the Chat Box!</h1>
    <button type="button" onClick={logoutEvent}>Logout</button>
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ickyrr/z1aL4skb/)

Comment: Hi, It's working very well, but I want to add a button in `ChatBox` Component not in parent Component itself.

Comment: I've added the `ChatBox` Component. You just have to do the same thing

Comment: Thanks it looks nice way.