# How to update parent's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am new to react and trying to update parent's state but no luck so far.

**Component**

```
class InputBox extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.type = props.type;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type={this.type}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Other container where I want to use this component to toggle password

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    type: 'password',
    wording: 'Show',
  };
  this.changeState = this.changeState.bind(this);
}

changeState() {
  const oldState = this.state.type;
  const isTextOrHide = (oldState === 'password');
  const newState = (isTextOrHide) ? 'text' : 'password';
  const newWord = (isTextOrHide) ? 'Hide' : 'Show';
  this.setState({
    type: newState,
    label: newWord,
  });
}

<Wrapper>
  <InputBox type={this.state.type} />
  <Toggle onClick={this.changeState}>{this.state.wording}</Toggle>
</Wrapper>
```

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs/38397755#38397755

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like this:

First, Parent component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { InputBox} from './InputBox'

class componentName extends Component {
  state = {
    password: '',
    type: 'password',
    wording: 'Show',
  }

  handleShow = (word) => {
    this.setState({ wording: word })
  }

  handleChange = (e) => {
    if(!this.state.password){ 
      handleShow('Show')
    } else  {
      handleShow('Hide')
    }
    this.setState({ password: e.target.value })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Wrapper>
          <InputBox
           name='password'  
           handleChange={this.handleChange} 
           password={this.state.password}
           type={this.state.type} /> . 
          <Toggle onClick={this.changeState}>{this.state.wording}
         </Toggle>
        </Wrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now the child component:

```
import React from 'react';

export const InputBox = (props) => (
  <input onChange={props.handleChange} value={props.password} type={props.type}/>
)
```

1. The `state` needs to always remain in the parent and then pass it down through `props`
2. The children components usually are stateless, which means, they don't need to be a `class` (can be just a function that returns `jsx` ) and the most import, can't have `state` (state is only available in `Class components`)

**Always pass the state down to children components** 
Because no matter how far down the `state` is, by being passed through `props` **it'll will always change the source, which in this case is the parent, the creator of the state**

another important thing:

If you use arrow functions ES6 , there's no need to have a `constructor` to bind your functions.

Like this:  `handleSomething = () => { return ... }`

another thing:

you don't need the `constructor` to set the `state`, you can simply do

```
state = { }
```

and it automatically become part of the context `this`

Thinking this way you'll never fail.

Hope it helped you :)

Answer (score 2):

```
class Child extends Component{
    constructor(props){
       super(props);
    }

    render(){
       let { parentStateChange } = this.props;
       return <input type='text' onChange={parentStateChange}/>
    }
}

class Parent extends Component{
    constructor(props){
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           content: "Something"
       }
       this.parentStateChange = this.parentStateChange.bind(this);
    }

    parentStateChange(event){
       let value = event.target.value;
       this.setState({
           content: value
       })
    }

    render(){
       let { content } = this.state;
       return <div>
           <h2>{content}</h2>
           <Child parentStateChange={this.parentStateChange}></Child>
         </div>
    }
}
```

I did it by passing a Parent's method to child as a props. Then Child has use this method to change Parent's state. It's called as Callback Functions.

[For More References](http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/)

I think this is useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

A more generic (but possibly bad approach).  Parent class has a function that is passed as callback to children and allows child calling setState directly.  I can only see this useful in a tightly bound small component with a few children or just for proof of concept code.

```
/**
  * This allows children to set state of this object.
  * Might be a very bad approach, btw.
  * 
  * @param {object} newState - object to update state.
  * @param {func} cb - call back after state is updated.
  */
 doSetState = (newState, cb=null) => {
    const merge = { ...this.state, ...newState };
    cb ? this.setState(merge, cb) : this.setState(merge);
}
```