# Update State from child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

I have 2 components, the first component is "Register" as the parent component and the second component is "UserCountry", first I run the "UserCountry" component and send the state to the API to get the data "country list", then I set it to localStorage which will later I am passing to the "Register / parent" component,
how do i set the state in the "Register" component
to add data that I got from the "UserCountry" component?

this is my parent component "Register"

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      MEMBER_FIRST_NAME:'',
      MEMBER_LAST_NAME:'',
      MEMBER_EMAIL:'',
      MEMBER_PASSWORD:'',
      MEMBER_PASSWORD2:'',
      ACCEPT_MARKETING:1
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(e){
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name] : e.target.value
    })
  }

  getIdCountry(){
    return this.setState({
      MEMBER_COUNTRY_ID:localStorage.getItem('country_id'),
      MEMBER_COUNTRY_NAME:localStorage.getItem('country_name'),
    })
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.getIdCountry();
  }

  async handleSubmit(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    await Api.post('member/register' , this.state)
    .then((response) => {
      let responJson = response
      console.log(responJson)
    })
  }
```

and this is a Child component "UserCountry" I will send the data obtained from the UserCountry component to the parent state of the "Register" component.

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      country: [],
    };
    this.handleSelect = this.handleSelect.bind(this)
  }

  async componentDidMount(){
    await Api.get('user-country', this.state)
    .then((response) => {
      let responseJson = response
      if(responseJson.data.STATUS_CODE === '200'){
        // this.props.resSave('country', JSON.stringify(responseJson.data.DATA))
        this.setState({
          country:response.data.DATA
        })
      }else{
        alert("ERR CONNECTION TIMEOUT")
      }
    })
  }

  handleSelect(e){
    if (this.refs.idCountry) {
      let strResult = this.refs.idCountry.value
      let conToArray = strResult.split(",")
      this.setState({
        MEMBER_COUNTRY_ID:conToArray[0],
        MEMBER_COUNTRY_NAME:conToArray[1]
      })
      this.props.resSave('country_id', conToArray[0])
      this.props.resSave('country_name', conToArray[1])
    }
  }
```

so later I hope like this (parent component)

```
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      MEMBER_FIRST_NAME:'',
      MEMBER_LAST_NAME:'',
      MEMBER_EMAIL:'',
      MEMBER_PASSWORD:'',
      MEMBER_PASSWORD2:'',
      ACCEPT_MARKETING:1,
     // new properties and values ​​obtained from child components
      MEMBER_COUNTRY_ID:localStorage.getItem('country_id'),
      MEMBER_COUNTRY_NAME:localStorage.getItem('country_name'),
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
```

I have tried it several times, the property has been successfully added but the value from localStorage I did not get

Comment: you can set function through  props to UserCountry and make callbak with params  that can change state in parent conrol,

Comment: what is the real example? I still do not understand just 1 month trying to react,thanks

Comment: Look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44661549/how-to-update-parents-state