# react js can't update props from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a logout button and when it's clicked nothing changes, even though there is a function call that does `setState({isLoggedIn: false})` I do have a `componentWillMount()` function to set it in the first place to what the props is because it wasn't changing to being true when I was set in the parent.

How do I fix this as react throws no errors. I have been looking at this for a good hour now with no avail.

some code

```
onLogOutClick(){
    this.setState({
       isLoggedIn: false,
    )}
}

componentWillMount(){
    this.setState({
        isLoggedIn: this.props.IsLoggedIn
    }, function(){

    });
}

...

{this.props.IsLoggedIn ? (
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li> 
                <button 
                    onClick={() => this.onLogOutClick()} 
                    className="form-control" 
                    style={{ 
                        marginTop: "10px", 
                        color: "black", 
                        border: "none" 
                    }} 
                >
                    <span className="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"/>
                    &nbsp;&nbsp;LogOut {this.state.Username}
                </button>
            </li>
        </ul>    
    ) : "LOGGED OUT" 
}
```

that changes from logged out to the button when logged in but doesnt work the other way around

Comment: can you show me more related codes.

Comment: you need to show more code for people to figure out what your issue is

Comment: show the code  !

Comment: @Natsathorn updated

Comment: @bRIMOs Updated

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri updated

Comment: onLogOutClick(){
    this.setState{isLoggedIn: false}
}

should do the trick

Comment: @L4reds thats how it is

Comment: is the function called? maybe console log something in that logout function just for debugging purpose

Comment: ok i will try that

Comment: @L4reds it gets there

Comment: {this.props.IsLoggedIn .... change it to this.state.IsLoggedIn

Comment: now it doesnt change from logged out to logged in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are setting the local state loggedIn and not the parent state which is passed down as props but you are using the loggedIn value from props.

What you should be doing is updating the parent state so that the props are updated.

In parent:

```
 onLogOutClick(){
    this.setState({
       isLoggedIn: false,
    )}
}
```

In child:

```
{this.props.IsLoggedIn ? <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li> <button onClick={() => this.props.onLogOutClick()} className="form-control" style={{ marginTop: "10px", color: "black", border: "none" }} ><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out " ></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;LogOut {this.state.Username}</button></li>
                        </ul>: "LOGGED OUT" }
```

Comment: check this answer to get a detailed view of how to communicate info to parent from child https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs/38397755#38397755

Comment: i will need to pass the function through the call for the child wont I

Comment: yeah you need to pass the function to child from parent :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the value of the props in the child component without triggering the event.
Here you checked the "this.props.IsLoggedIn" which is comes from the parent component and you are trying to change the state of child component. You can check the  "this.state.isLoggedIn" in place of "this.props.IsLoggedIn" for correct working your code.

Code Before Editing :

```
 {this.props.IsLoggedIn ? <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li> <button onClick={() => this.onLogOutClick()} className="form-control" style={{ marginTop: "10px", color: "black", border: "none" }} ><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out " ></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;LogOut {this.state.Username}</button></li>
                        </ul>: "LOGGED OUT" }
```

Code After Editing :

```
{this.state.isLoggedIn ? <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li> <button onClick={() => this.onLogOutClick()} className="form-control" style={{ marginTop: "10px", color: "black", border: "none" }} ><span className="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out " ></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;LogOut {this.state.Username}</button></li>
                        </ul>: "LOGGED OUT" }
```