# React Native: Change state or property of parent from child component

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, state

Suppose I have a class called HomeScreen and it has Location, and Person as Components:

```
HomeScreen contains the component Location:

constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          location: '',
      }
    }

    export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
    ...
      render() {
        const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
        return (
                 <Location 
                    navigator={this.props.navigation}
                    ></Location>
                 <Person location={this.state.location} />
        )}
    }
```

Location Class:

```
export default class LocationSelector extends Component{
        constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            location: '',
            region: '',
        }
    }

   onSelect = fullLocation => {
    var location = fullLocation.location;
    this.setState({location: location});
   }

    render(){
        return (
                  <View>
                     <TouchableOpacity
                     onPress={() => this.props.navigator.navigate('Location',{ onSelect: this.onSelect })}>
                     </TouchableOpacity>
                   </View>
             )
   }
}
```

Person Class:

```
class  Person extends Component{

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      distance: 2,
    }
  }

    static defaultProps = {
      location:  '',
    }

  componentWillReceiveProps (nextProps) {
    this.setState({distance: 4});
  }

  render () {
    return <Text>Person: {this.props.location} distance : {this.state.distance}</Text>;
  }
}
```

*Description of the codes:*
[image: explaining the long codes]

**HomeScreen**(state=> location) is the first class to be seen, from here **Location**(state=>location) component is added . 
Now in Location class its **location state is initialised** . 
And in **Person**(prop=>location, state=> distance) class I need that value to re-render the Person component to provide a state called distance dynamically.

**My question is how can I get the value from Location component and set it to HomeScreen state and pass the same value to Person class ?**

I am using **componentWillReceiveProps**() to reload the Person Component .

Comment: are you using redux?

Comment: No I am not. For this small task , I think it's not worth to add redux.

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs/38397755#38397755