# Passing a prop to a different component in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
clickMusicHandler() {

    //console.log(this.props.channel);

    axios.put('/channels/'+'test', {

        playList: {
            songName: this.props.track.name,
            artist: this.props.track.artists[0].name,
            url: this.props.track.preview_url
        }
    })
        .then((res)=>{

            //set state

        console.log("added song");
    }).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
    });   

}
```

In my component called `SongList` I want to pass in a `this.props.track.preview_url` to a different component that uses this component when an item of the component `SongList` is clicked. The code above is a click handler for a `SongList` item.

I want to add `this.props.track.preview_url` to a local array of the component that is using this component.

In the component that is using `SongList` it looks like :

```
    const mapToComponents = (data) => {

        if(this.state.keyword == '') return [];

        return data.map((eachData, index) => {
            return (  <SongList track = { eachData } key={ index }/>  );
        });
    };
```

How can I add the url of the clicked item of `SongList` to a local array called `this.testSongList = [];` of the component using `SongList`?

Answer (score 0):

This question addresses how to pass data from a child component to its parent: [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

In your case, you would pass the `clickMusicHandler` as a prop to `SongList`, which updates the parent component.

However, if you would like the state to be consistent across multiple components, I suggest using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/%22Redux%22). Redux is a JS state container which allows you to bind props to state variables. When you run the click handler, dispatch the new `preview_url` to the store, and your other component will automatically re-render with the new value.

[Getting Started with Redux](https://egghead.io/courses/getting-started-with-redux)