# How to remove an instance of a React component class instantiated by its parent's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

(Pardon the verbose question. I'm brand new to React and ES6, and I'm probably overly-convoluting this.)

I am writing an app that contains a button component. This button calls a method `onAddChild` that creates another component of class `ColorModule` by adding a value to an array stored in the App's state.

In each newly created `ColorModule`, I want to include another button that will remove the module. Since this component is created by an `array.map` method, my thought is that if I can find the index of the array item that corresponds with the component and use that index in `array.splice` then perhaps that component will be removed (untested theory). That said, I'm not really sure how to find the index where I would use this in my `onRemoveModule` method.

Two part question: 1) How would I go about finding the index of the array item in my state, and 2) if I'm completely off base or there's a better way to do this altogether, what does that solution look like?

```
imports...

class App extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // Here's the array in question...
      moduleList: [1],
    };
    this.onAddChild = this.onAddChild.bind(this);
    this.onRemoveModule = this.onRemoveModule.bind(this);
    this.className = bemClassName.bind(null, this.constructor.name);
  }

  onAddChild(module) {
    const moduleList = this.state.moduleList;
    this.setState({ moduleList: moduleList.concat(1) });
  }

  onRemoveModule( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    ...¯\_(ツ)_/¯
  }

  render() {
    const { className } = this;

    return (
      <div className={className('container')}>
        <Header onAddChild={this.onAddChild} /> /* Add module button lives here */
        <div className="cf">
          {this.state.moduleList.map(
            ( delta, index ) => {
              return (
                <ColorModule
                  className="cf"
                  onRemove={this.onRemoveModule}
                  key={index}
                  moduleId={'colorModule' + index}
                />
              ); /* Remove module button would live in the module itself */
            }
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: i will suggest that instead of storing 1 in  moduleList array in state, put a unique id for identification of element and use that id as key, as well as pass that to child component, use that id to remove the component.

Comment: @MayankShukla great advice -- done and thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Well this part is pretty easy, all you need to do is pass the `index` as prop to the `ColorModule` component and when calling the `onRemove` method in it you could pass it back to the `onRemoveModule`. However react optimizes based on keys and its a really good idea to have a unique id given to each module instance.

```
class App extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node,
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      // Here's the array in question...
      moduleList: [1],
    };
    this.onAddChild = this.onAddChild.bind(this);
    this.onRemoveModule = this.onRemoveModule.bind(this);
    this.className = bemClassName.bind(null, this.constructor.name);
  }

  onAddChild(module) {
    const moduleList = this.state.moduleList;
    this.setState({ moduleList: moduleList.concat(uuid()) }); //uuid must return a unique id everytime to be used as component key
  }

  onRemoveModule( index ) {
        // now with this index you can update the moduleList
  } 

  render() {
    const { className } = this;

    return (
      <div className="cf">
          {this.state.moduleList.map(
            ( delta, index ) => {
              return (
                <ColorModule
                  className="cf"
                  index={index}
                  onRemove={this.onRemoveModule}
                  key={delta}
                  moduleId={'colorModule' + delta}
                />
              ); 
            }
          )}
        </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Now in ColorModule component

```
class ColorModule extends React.Component {

     onRemoveClick=() => {
         this.props.onRemove(this.props.index);
     }

}
```

Check this answer for more details on **[how to pass data from `Child` component to `Parent`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs/38397755#38397755)**

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this problem using some of the guidance here from @ShubhamKhatri (didn't know about unique ID generation!), but I took a slightly different approach and handled the solution using state manipulation in `App` without needing a new method in my `ColorModule` component. I also never knew about currying in ES6, so that discovery made passing in the index values needed to manipulate my state array possible

If I'm off-base here or being inefficient, I'm definitely still open to feedback on a better way!

```
class App extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      moduleList: [{ id: UniqId(), removeModule: false }],
    };
    this.onAddChild = this.onAddChild.bind(this);
    this.className = bemClassName.bind(null, this.constructor.name);
  }

  onAddChild(module) {
    const moduleList = this.state.moduleList;
    this.setState({
      moduleList: moduleList.concat({
        id: UniqId(),
        removeModule: false,
      }),
    });
  }

  onRemoveModule = ( i, arr ) => (e) => {
    const moduleList = this.state.moduleList;
    e.preventDefault();
    moduleList[i].removeModule = true;
    this.setState({ moduleList: moduleList });
  }

  render() {
    const { className } = this;

    return (
      <div className={className('container')}>
        <Header onAddChild={this.onAddChild} />
        <div className="cf">
          {this.state.moduleList.map(
            ( delta, index ) => {
              if ( !this.state.moduleList[index].removeModule ) {
                return (
                  <ColorModule
                    className="cf"
                    onRemove={this.onRemoveModule( index, this.state.moduleList )}
                    index={index}
                    key={delta.id}
                    moduleId={'colorModule' + delta}
                  />
                );
              }
            }
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```