# React how to link child component onClick to parent state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am creating a `Modal` component and on a high level, it looks like this:

```
class Modal extends Component {
    hideModal() {
        /* logic to hide modal */
    }       

    render() {
        return (
            <section role="dialog" ... >
                <div className="modal-inner">
                    <header className="react-modal-header">{this.props.title}</header>
                    <div className="react-modal-body">{this.props.body}</div>
                    <footer className="react-modal-footer">{this.props.footer}</footer>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

I want to provide a way for consumers of this component to specify a button that closes the modal. I was thinking of putting this button in its own component like so:

```
class ModalCloseButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={/* call hideModal in Modal component */}>
                {this.props.text}
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

The `Modal` component and the `ModalCloseButton` component would be used this way:

```
<Modal
    title="my awesome modal"
    body="this is the body of my awesome component"
    footer={
        <ModalCloseButton text="Close modal!"/>
    } 
/>
```

How can I link the `Modal` and `ModalCloseButton` components so that the `onClick` handler in the button component triggers the `hideModal` function in the `Modal` component?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs/38397755#38397755)

Comment: It's different case - here data must be passed from Parent to element which is passed as prop to Parent (not from Child to Parent)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:

https://codepen.io/JanickFischr/pen/JLRovb

You can give the child a prop with a function.

```
onClick={this.props.function}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor function inside the parent:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.hideModal = this.hideModal.bind(this)
}
```

Then pass it into your child like so:

```
<ModalCloseButton hideModal={this.hideModal} />
```

Then in your child you can call it:

```
<button onClick={() => this.props.hideModal()}>click me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a callback function to the modal component and then pass that callback to the buttonClose component. When onClick you execute that callback, and receive the event from the parent

Answer (score 0):

In Modal component you can extend passed Button element with additional prop holding reference to `hideModal` method using [React.cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement):

```
class Modal extends Component {
    hideModal() {
        /* logic to hide modal */
    }       

    render() {
        const ButtonWithHide = React.cloneElement(this.props.footer, { hide: this.hideModal.bind(this)}));;
        return (
            <section role="dialog" ... >
                <div className="modal-inner">
                    <header className="react-modal-header">{this.props.title}</header>
                    <div className="react-modal-body">{this.props.body}</div>
                    <footer className="react-modal-footer">
                         <ButtonWithClose />
                    </footer>
                </div>
            </section>
        );
    }
}
```

and in Button component set passed method as onClick handler:

```
class ModalCloseButton extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <button type="button" onClick={this.props.hide}>
                {this.props.text}
            </button>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add a state varible in modal(hide=true) and set visiblity of that modal on the basis of that modal. create a method  hideModal() that toggle to the state variable in your Modal component, after that pass this method to the ModalCloseButton component as a props and call that method onClick of button in ModalCloseButton component.

class Modal extends Component {
        constructor(props){
          super(props)
    this.state={
    hide:true,
    }
        hideModal() {
    this.setState({
    hide:false,
    })
        }
        render() {
            return (
                
                    
                        {this.props.title}
                        {this.props.body}
                        {this.props.footer}
                    
    {this.hideModal()}}/>
                
            );
        }
    }
    class ModalCloseButton extends Component {
        render() {
            return (
                
                    {this.props.text}
                
            );
        }
    }