# how does elementUI make child component pass data to parent component?

Tags: reactjs

related links:[how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

**In Parent Component:**

```
getData(val) {
    // do not forget to bind getData in constructor
    console.log(val);
}

render() {
    return(<Child sendData={this.getData}/>);
}
```

**In Child Component:**

```
demoMethod() {
    this.props.sendData(value);
}
```

The proposed solution is to use a function property to pass the value from the child to parent component.

---

**This is how the elementUI library code look like:**

```
class Example extends Component{
    //constructor()
    this.state={
        value:''
    }
}

render() {
    return (
        <Input value={this.state.value}></Input>
    );
}
```

In elementUI they pass a variable and not a function.

How does elementUI make the child and parent component have a two-way data binding?

Comment: do you refer to [this library](https://eleme.github.io/element-react/#/en-US/quick-start) or [elementalUI](http://elemental-ui.com/)?

Answer (score 1):

I took a quick look at [the documentation for elementUI for React](https://eleme.github.io/element-react/#/en-US/quick-start) and found it a bit sparse. There is not enough detail to really say.

There are really two possibilities:

1. The documentation is simply not clear.

Looking at [the documentation for the `Input` component](https://eleme.github.io/element-react/#/en-US/input), there is no mention of an `onChange` property. Is this an oversight? Perhaps, because there is a reference to `props.onChange` in the source for the `Input` element.

2. The developers are doing something funky with the `Form` element

**What follows is conjecture - I have not examined the elementUI source in enough detail to say that this is what it is doing.**

That said, it is possible in React for a parent component to examine and modify the properties of children. Looking at the docs for elementUI, it appears you're supposed to do something like this:

```
<Form>
    <Input value={this.state.myValue} />
</Form>
```

When the `Form` element renders, it may be adding a new prop (say, `onChange`) into the `Input` component. It may also be manipulating the `value` property of the `Input` to modify it as necessary in response to changes. This allows the `Form` element and it's children to handle all the back-and-forth of `onChange`/`value` property changes.

Answer (score 0):

There is no two way data flow in React. You can imagine the data flow as a waterfall. The root element contains all the water (or: data) and passes it down in the tree of components.

If you want a parent component to be aware of the data, you need to keep it in its state and pass it down to the parents child components.

Read this for a detailled explanation: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down