# Send data from child to parent React

Tags: reactjs

I don`t know where i do wrong.I cant send data from child to parent.
What is wrong here?
How can i grab the state from child and send to parent state?

this is the child component

```
import React from 'react';

export class Child extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      counter2: 5
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.data}>Click me</button><span>{this.state.counter2}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

and i want to update the state in parent component

```
import React from 'react';
import {Child} from './Child';

export default class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      counter: 0
    }
  }

  update(){
    this.setState({
      counter: this.props.state.counter2
    });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <span>{this.state.counter}</span>
        <Child data={this.update.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

but i have a error:
×
TypeError: Cannot read property 'counter' of undefined?

i cant understand what i do wrong!

Thank you

Comment: What is this `this.props.state.counter` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, you don't have `state` property in your Parent's `props`.
You **can't** get child's state in a such way:

```
this.props.state.counter2
```

Props **ONLY** passed from parent component to child (if you don't use `Redux` or another state management library).

Nevertheless, you can pass it like this:

**Parent component**

```
import React from 'react';
import {Child} from './Child';

export default class Parent extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      counter: 0
    }
  }

  update(value){
    return () => {
       this.setState({
         counter: value
       });
    }
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <span>{this.state.counter}</span>
        <Child data={this.update.bind(this)}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Child component**

```
import React from 'react';

export class Child extends React.Component{
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state= {
      counter2: 5
    }
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.props.data(this.state.counter2)}>Click me</button><span>{this.state.counter2}</span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Child;
```

Answer (score 2):

You are not passing `content2` state in the child component correctly

You need to pass it with the button

```
 <button onClick={()=> this.props.data(this.state.counter2)}>Click me</button><span>{this.state.counter2}</span>
```

Then in your update function

```
  update = (data) =>{
    this.setState({
      counter: data
    });
  }
```

> Note: no need to bind update function if you are using arrow function
>   like me.

```
  <div>
    <span>{this.state.counter}</span>
    <Child data={this.update)}/>
  </div>
```

Comment: This won't work. `onClick` handler should take reference for function. In your case it will get `undefined`.

Comment: You are calling the function rather than passing it.

Comment: It's not related to binding at all. I'm talking about different thing. You're calling `this.props.data(this.state.counter2)` during rendering. Function `update` is evaluated and returns `undefined` to the event listener.

Comment: Ooh yes I forgot to put arrow function to onClick in the child component

Comment: Thank you for letting me know :)