# Handling onchange in two stateful components in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and so confused in handling and calling the onChange events.

Now , I have 2 components :-

```
    1. Parent component - 

  updateField = e => {
        console.log("update field e called");
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        });
    };

  <InputTypeahead value={this.state.value} label="Email" onChange={this.updateField} typeaheadItems={this.emailAdressess} /
```

> where I am calling the onChange and taking the current value out. Till
>   now whatever I type in Input I get the value.

Now,

```
2.In Child component :

I want to take the value coming from this parent component and using that would like to setstate.

How to achieve this in React js ? I have tried using refs , but result was not successful.
```

Any Help is appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From version i.e **16.3.0** onwards, you can make use of getDerivedStateFromProps method to update the state based on props like

```
class InputTypeahead extends React.Component {
    state = {
       value: ''
    }
    static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
        if(nextProps.value !== prevState.value) {
           return { value: nextProps.value};
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

According to the **[docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops)**:

> `getDerivedStateFromProps` is invoked after a component is
>   instantiated as well as when it receives new props. It should return
>   an object to update state, or null to indicate that the new props do
>   not require any state updates.

Before **v16.3.0**, you would make use of constructor along with componentWillReceiveProps like

```
class InputTypeahead extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this.state = {
           value: props.value
       }
    } 
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if(nextProps.value !== this.props.value) {
           this.setState({ value: nextProps.value});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you shubham.But in project we are using 16.2.Could you please guide ?

Comment: Updated the answer for that, please check

Comment: Thanks shubham ..I Ignored the lifecycle hooks ..haha :)

Comment: @pourushsinghgaur, lifecycle hooks are the best thing in React and its best to know which lifecycle are called at what times. Anyways glad to have helped

Comment: Sure I ll Improve my knowledge to that.I want to understand one thing , In my parent component---m calling on change--capturing the calue entered by user.In child component I need to call , Child's onchange so that I can setState.

Comment: By taking the value in componentWillReceiveProps and setting the state gives me all the time the value that user entered.In my case I need to capture the value from say a suggestion list or a typeahead list.

Comment: As a rule , you must have a single source of truth, so you must ideally store the value in parent and modify the same , instead of updating state in child based on props. Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs/38397755#38397755

Comment: Okay , I got this point how to return some value from child to parent component through props.But Another thing is In Parent -->i am setting state as this.setState({e.target.value}) ;So if I return some value from child to parent as props to the same onChange function-->It gives errors like target is undefined !

Comment: Could you please guide how to handle this scenario pls ?