# Reactjs Passing props from the child

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I got the property from the child but how can I pass to the parent?

in parent.js

```
<Child childId={() => this.getchildId()} />

getchildId = (id) => { 
   // do something 
   console.log(id) // return undefined
}
```

in child.js

```
const id = "something";

<Item itemid={this.getId(id)} />

getId = (id) => { 
    console.log(id); // return "something"
    this.props.childId(id)
}
```

**Update!**
It works with

in parent.js

```
<Child childId={this.getchildId} />
```

Now the problem is they are keep being called...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Comment: you're doing well, only you need `.bind(this)` to all methods

Comment: He probably doesn't. He is using arrow functions.

Comment: @JorgeFélixCazarez I used the arrow functions, do I still need `.bind(this)` ?

Comment: @susuwatari nevermind I see that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// in parent
getchildId = (id) => { 
   // do something 
   console.log(id) // return undefined
}

<FirstChild logChildId={this.getchildId}


// in FirstChild 
<SecondChild logChildId={props.logChildId} />

// in SecondChild
<button onClick={() => props.logChildId("test")}>
click me
</button>
```

so it's just passing down the function pointer via props

Can you show the code for your `<Item />` component? make sure that the function isn't directly invoked and only referenced by arrow function just as I pointed out in second child, or via method if you are writing a class function

```
// in SecondChild

handleLogChildId = (id) => {
  const { logChildId } = this.props
  logChildId(id)
}

<button onClick={this.handleLogChildId("test")}>
click me
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Child childId={this.getchildId} />

getchildId = (id) => { 
 // do something 
 console.log(id) // return undefined
 }
```

In parent.js just pass the function reference.

Comment: It works, it got the id in parent.js. Any ideas why they are being for so many time?

Answer (score 0):

Passing anything from child to parent is very simple via functions.

let assume you have a parent like this

```
class Parent extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  this._getProps = this._getProps.bind(this);
 }
 _getProps(data) { // Here you will receive the props data from child component.
  console.log(data);
 }
 render(){
  return (
   <Child getProps = {this._getProps}/>
  );
 }
}


class Child extends Component {
 constructor(props){
  this._sendProps = this._sendProps.bind(this);
 }
 _sendProps(data) {
  this.props.getProps(data); // This will send your props data to parent function.
 }
 render(){
  return (
   <div> </div>
  );
 }
}
```