# Passing child component data to parent using props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am completely new to ReactJS. I have a component (Component A) where I want to click a button and fetch a token from an API using AJAX call. Once the fetch is successful I need to pass it to another component (Component B) and render it conditionally (https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html).

Both Component A and B are nested within a single parent component and should render conditionally.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ComponentA />
        or
        <ComponentB>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**Expected result:**

`ComponentA` should fetch the token within itself and pass to its `Parent`, there by notifying to replace `ComponentA` and render `ComponentB`.

**Code I tried:**

I took an example from here: https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/QKzAgB?editors=0010 and [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs) and wrote the below code.

```
class ComponentA extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.handleGenerateToken = this.handleGenerateToken.bind(this);
    }

    handleGenerateToken(){
      console.log("gen token");
      axios({ 
        method: 'post',
        url: 'https://<token_url>',
        mode: 'no-cors'
      }).then((result) => {
        if(result.status === 200){
          console.log({token:result.data});
          this.props.onGenerateToken({token:result.data}); //it fails here
        }else{
          console.log("Error generating token. Status code: " + result.status);
        }
      });
    }

    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <div id="details" className="div-center">
            some ui
            <div>
            <a id="btnStart" onClick={this.handleGenerateToken} className="waves-effect waves-light btn secondary-content">Start</a>
            <a id="btnReset" className="waves-effect waves-grey btn blue-grey lighten-5 black-text outline secondary-content">Reset</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
}
```

Problem is I get the token but unable to set it to the props using `this.props`. I get below which seems like `this` is not accessible.

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _this4.props.onGenerateToken is not a
>   function
>       at :182:26

I tried creating an extra variable `_self` and assign `this` outside the `Promise` scope of the AJAX call but that didn't work.

I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. Please let me know if I can explain in more detail.

Comment: You need to show the code where your component is used (`onGenerateToken` is probably undefined or something else that's not a function)! Also, `console.log(this.props)`

Comment: So where does onGenerateToken() come from?

Comment: Check `onGenerateToken` is a prop in another component. Also check where this is pointing in that context

Comment: @ThiefMaster It is not defined. I thought I can use it just like that and pick it up from parent component.

Comment: No, that's not how react works...

Comment: You need to define that prop first on that component.

Comment: @MeetZaveri Can you show me a small sample?

Comment: You must pass a function in the onGenerateToken prop to this component where you actually use it, should look something like `<GuestGreeting onGenerateToken={myFunction} />`

Comment: @SouvikGhosh Okay I have posted an answer. Please check if you find something useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple example :

Let `<ComponentA/>` be your component:

```
 handleGenerateToken(){
  console.log("gen token");
  axios({ 
    method: 'post',
    url: 'https://<token_url>',
    mode: 'no-cors'
  }).then((result) => {
    if(result.status === 200){
      console.log({token:result.data});
      this.props.onGenerateToken({token:result.data}); //it will have a handler in wrapper(parent) component
    }else{
      console.log("Error generating token. Status code: " + result.status);
    }
  });
}
```

Let `<Parent/>` be the component you have wrapped this `<ComponentA/>` and `<ComponentB/>`. Conditionally render components on basis of boolean like flag `isTokenAvailable` defined in state

In `<Parent/>`'s render method :

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            isTokenAvailable: false,
            token:null
        };
    }

    render() {
        const isTokenAvailable = this.state.isTokenAvailable;
        return (
            <div>
                {isTokenAvailable ? (
                    <ComponentB />
                ) : (
                    <ComponentA
                        onGenerateToken={(token) => {
                            this.setState({ isTokenAvailable: true, token });
                        }}
                    />
                )}
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question and added more details to simplify it. Can you please check?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh I have updated the answer. Can you check and confirm if its helpful?

Comment: It works. So, I am trying to pass `token` from `this.state.token` to `ComponentB` like `<UserGreeting token={this.state.token}/>` but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What's the value being shownig `<UserGreeting/>` component ? Is it null or actual value ?

Comment: I have explained in the updated details. Can you please check?

Comment: nevermind. it's working. had to use `this.setState`.

Answer (score 0):

Change `this.handleGenerateToken` to `this.handleGenerateToken()` or `handleGenerateToken(){` to `handleGenerateToken = () => {`

And instead of changing props, just use state :)

```
state = { token: undefined };
constructor(props){
      super(props);
      this.handleGenerateToken = this.handleGenerateToken.bind(this);
}
```

and then just simply

```
this.setstate({token:result.data});
```

Then you can render it conditionaly

```
render(){
if(this.state.token === undefined){
   return <Text>Oh, Token is undefined</Text>
}
   return <Text>Token is defined</Text>
}
```

Comment: I have updated my question and added more details to simplify it. Can you please check?

Comment: @SouvikGhosh Change `this.handleGenerateToken` to `this.handleGenerateToken()` or `handleGenerateToken(){` to `handleGenerateToken = () => {`

Comment: The token which you have set is actually generated from a child component. You can only set the state when you have the token in the parent component. So how do you pass the token from child to parent?

Answer (score 0):

[react doc](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

change

```
handleGenerateToken(){
```

to

```
handleGenerateToken = () => {
```

Comment: I have updated my question and added more details to simplify it. Can you please check?