# ReactJS, is it possible to reference an object in another component without using document.getElementbyId?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

I am creating an application that shows charts and to load the chart, I need to write the following lines of code:

```
const line_chart = new GoogleCharts.api.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart-div'));
line_chart.draw(data, options);
```

This `chart-div` is inside another component called `<ChartComponent/>`.
Is it possible to access `chart-div` without using `document.getElementById`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use react refs and pass the reference through props.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
  }
  render() {
    return <div ref={this.myRef} />;
  }
}
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: How do I pass the reference through props?

Comment: like any other prop: `<MyComponent coolReference={this.myRef} />`

Comment: That will allow us to pass the prop from parent to child not from child to parent. I am checking other SO questions that explain how it is possible. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs