# How to pass child index to parent

Tags: reactjs

I need to remove one row data from array. I don't know how to pass the index of this row from child to parent. Below is my code:
App.js

```
 state = {
      courses: [{course:'' }] 
  }
  onDelete(index){
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
      courses: prevState.courses.filter((_, i) => i !== index)
    }));  
  }
  render() {
     const courses = this.state.courses.map((course, i) => {
      return (
        <ClassItem index={i}  onDelete={this.onDelete(i)} />
      );
    });
    return (
      <div>
         {courses}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Child component:

```
 class ClassItem extends Component {
 onDelet(index){
   this.props.onDelete(index);
 }
  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  placeholder="Course Name" ></input></td> 

         <td>
         <button  onClick={this.onDelete} /></td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

export default ClassItem;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs

Comment: Glad I could help - can you accept my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're nearly there. In your parent you need to capture the value of your index by closing over it by declaring a function and passing it to `onDelete`.

```
render() {
   const courses = this.state.courses.map((course, i) => {
     return (
      <ClassItem index={i} onDelete={() => this.onDelete(i)} />
  )}
)}
```

Then in your Child, you just call the `onDelete` prop:

```
class ClassItem extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  placeholder="Course Name"></input</td> 
        <td><button onClick={this.props.onDelete}/></td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}

export default ClassItem;
```

An alternative to capturing your `index` in the parent is to use the index that you're passing in as a prop in your child:

```
class ClassItem extends Component {

 render() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text"  placeholder="Course Name"></input</td> 
        <td><button onClick={()=>this.props.onDelete(this.props.index)}/></td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
}
```

Which means you only have to pass in a reference to `this.onDelete`, instead of wrapping it in another function:

```
render() {
   const courses = this.state.courses.map((course, i) => {
     return (
      <ClassItem index={i} onDelete={this.onDelete} />
  )}
)}
```

**Edited to add:**

Doh, forgot that there's another problem with using a map index like this - as you're deleting items you'll need to use a unique and unchanging key for each item so the diffing engine knows which items to keep track of. So don't use the `i` index when you map over your courses, use a unique key instead and use that to filter your items in `this.onDelete`.

Comment: This works. I have not learned the redux yet. Why should I use call back function onDelete={()=>this.onDelete(i)} in the parent? Is it because it is called from Child component? Thanks.

Comment: Great! You only need to declare it as a function here because you want to capture the index. I'll update my answer to show what I mean.