# How to access a ref using React-Redux >= v6.0?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

in React-Redux >= v6.0 `connnect()` options support a new parameter, `forwardRef: boolean`.

> If {forwardRef : true} has been passed to connect, adding a ref to the connected wrapper component will actually return the instance of the wrapped component.

So, in my HoC called 'WithFields' I write:

```
 [...]
 import Form from '.../components/form';

   const WithFields = (arg1, arg2) => (WrappedComponent) => connect(mapStateToProps, {someMethod}, null, {forwardRef: true})(class extends React.Component {
 [...]

   render(
        return(<WrappedComponent ref={ref => this.wrappedComponent = ref }/>)
    )
}

   [...]

   let Customer = WithFields('a', 'b')(Form);
    export default Customer;
```

Now, in a Ticket component, I would to get the Customer ref with a method, but how?

```
     import Customer from '....';

      class Ticket extends Component {

           SOME_METHOD_TO_GET_THE_REF_OF_THE_HOC_COMPONENT() {
                  ?????????
             }

           render() {
               [....]

               <Customer/> 
            }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, re-checked also the React docs (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html), this is how to implement `ref` to the wrapped component of an HoC that uses React-Redux for the state management.

**hoc.js**

```
[...]
 import Form from '.../components/form';

   const WithFields = (arg1, arg2) =>
   (WrappedComponent) =>
    connect(mapStateToProps, {someMethod}, null, {forwardRef: true})(class extends React.Component {
 [...]

   render(
        return(<WrappedComponent ref={ref => this.formComponent = ref }/>)
    )
}

   [...]

   let Customer = WithFields('a', 'b')(Form);
   export default Customer;
```

**ticket.js**

```
 import Customer from '....';

      class Ticket extends Component {

           constructor(props) {
              super(props);
               this.customer = React.createRef();
            }

           triggerCustomerMethod (e) {

                let form = ref.current.formComponent; // THIS IS HOW YOU GET THE <Form/> component wrapped in <Customer/> 

                // example: get the <Form/> state and use it as argument for Hoc onSubmit() method (that updates the Redux store)
                let state = form.state;

                form.props.onSubmit(state, e);
           };


           render() {
               [....]

               <Customer ref={this.customer}/>

               <Button onClick={this.triggerCustomerMethod.bind(this)} text="Save"/> // clicking on button we launch triggerCustomerMethod()
            }
   }
```

Answer (score -2):

Pass this function from your Ticket component to the HOC as props

```
  getRef = (refvalue) => { setState({value: refValue})}
```

and inside the HOC consume `props` like this

```
 props.getRef(value of ref here)
```

Ticket component

```
  const Ticket = () => {
 const getRef = (value) => {
//do something with the value
}

return <Customer handleRef={getRef}/>
}
```

Customer Component

```
  const Customer = props => {
 OnChange = (refvalue) => {
 props.handleRef(refvalue)
}

return {....}
}
```

For more detailed answer check this [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Comment: Not, the returned component from the HOC is `Customer`. `Customer` is imported in  `Ticket` and I want to get the `Customer` ref inside `Ticket`.

Comment: I have just added the answer let me know if it's clear to you

Comment: No, it's not clear, what `setState` has to do with ref?

Comment: You are just saving it as your state in your Ticket component. That's just an example you can do anything with the value there.

Comment: See the answer now I have explained it more now

Comment: I have added link about passing data from child component to parent component. Hope that will explain you more about this