# Passing data back to component by react-native navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have main `App.js` where i implemented `StackNavigator`:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
          <Stack.Screen name="MainPage" component={MainPage} />
          <Stack.Screen name="Submit" component={Submit} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

What i want to do is Pass data from `Submit` component into my `MainPage` and display it in `ScrollView` from `array: arr` in `state` of `MainPage`.

`Mainpage` looks like this. I want to pass function `addNode` to adding node into `state` of my `MainPage`:

```
class MainPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      arr: [],
      liters: '',
      time: '',
    };
  }

  addNode = (time, liters) => {
    if (this.state.time) {
      this.state.arr.push({calc: time + liters});
      this.setState({time: ''});
      this.setState({liters: ''});
    }
  };

  onPress = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Submit', {addNode: this.addNode});
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <ScrollView>{this.state.arr}</ScrollView>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}>
          <Text>+</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

My `Submit` component looks like this. on button `Submit` i want to pass data from inputs to `MainPage`, add it to array and then display it in scroll view:

```
class Submit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      liters: '',
      time: '',
    };
  }

  goBack() {
    this.props.navigation.goBack();
    this.props.navigation.state.params.addNode({
      time: this.state.time,
      liters: this.state.liters,
    });

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Form</Text>
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={time => this.setState({time})}
          value={this.state.time}
        />
        <TextInput
          onChangeText={liters => this.setState({liters})}
          value={this.state.liters}
        />
        <Button title="Submit" onPress={this.goBack} />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

When i click `Submit` from my `Submit` component i get error presented in this screen:

[image]

My question is, how to pass data back to `parent` component from `children` component using `StackNavigator`? What im doing wrong here?

Comment: Are you able to try this person's example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs

Comment: thanks, but i think its more `reacte-native` related topic