# How to change parent component's state from child component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

How to change parent component's state from child component?, Also I need to pass some data from child component. Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you

Comment: Pass a function via props from parent to child.

Comment: okay but how to pass data from child to parent

Comment: The same way - a function that sets the state of the parent.

Comment: Please check this post: [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs/38397755#38397755)

Comment: Please review https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Answer (score 1):

Try to understand from this example

```
const Parent = ()=>{
    const [name,setName]=useState("");
    const handleName = (name)=>setName(name);
    const inputProps= {
        handleName:handleName
    }
    return (
        <>
            <div>My name is :{name}
            <Child props={inputProps} />
        </>
    )
}

const Child =(props)=>{
    const[name,setName]=useState("");
    useEffect(()=>
       props.handleName(name);  
    },[name])
    return(
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" 
        value={name} onChnage={(e)=>setName(e.target.value)} 
        />
    )
}
```

In this example the Parent Component Changes its state based on the changes in the Child Component. 
Child Component is just a input tag, on change of which triggers the effect hook which passes the value to the parent handler passed as a props. and displays the changed state.

I hope this helps!!