# Unable to pass data from Child Functional Component to React Parent Component (React.js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props, dataflow, react-state

I am building an Autocomplete component in react so I can render individual autocomplete(s) in a single page; I want to render the suggestions from Autocomplete in a separate component.

I tried using

```
class Parent extends Component {

    getData = (data) => {
        if (data) return data;
    };

    render () {
        <AutoComplete passData={this.getData} />
        // after some other elements
        {this.getData()}
    }

}
```

and

```
export const Child = (props) => {
    ...
    const updateSuggestion = (suggestions) => {
        this.props.passData(suggestions);
    }
}
```

But somehow, it's failing me. To confuse me even more, if I just console.log the retrieved data using the code below, it works perfectly!

```
getData = (data) => {
    if (data) console.log(data);
};
```

To complicate things even further, it fails me even if I return a hard-coded element:

```
getData = (data) => {
    if (data) return <p>Hello</p>;
};
```

Although it works when I remove `if (data)`

I'm completely lost as to what's happening here and would appreciate the slightest of help!

Comment: P.S. By "failing me", I mean it doesn't return anything at all

Comment: you are not storing your data anywhere for later retrieval.

Comment: How do I store data in the Parent Class?

Comment: `this.props.passData(suggestions);` don't use `this` in functional component like Child. It gets `props` as a paramater so it should be `props.passData(suggestions);`. :)

Comment: @Deykun I just updated my code and it seems like the data is flowing to the Parent Class but there's one more problem: it only works when I `console.log(suggestions)`
but not with `return suggestions`

Comment: I was only pointing an issue with scope, not solving the problem.

Comment: @Deykun ohh my bad

Comment: @matvs Yeah it does! Turns out I needed to store the data from child in parent's state and only then use it somewhere.. that helped alot =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use

```
{this.getData()}
```

when component will render for first time these `{this.getData()}` will not have data

Instead of returning data you need to use state method that will that will render component again so that your data will show up on inside render
see this
Post [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)