# Access child function from parent using refs when the child is a function component and the parent does not return JSX

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

It's a bit of a wordy title. What I am saying is I have a child component (which is a function component) and also a parent class. However this parent class does not return JSX therefore meaning I can't use hooks / `useRef()`. I also can't just add a ref to the child component since I get this error:

```
Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?
```

Here's the child class with a bit of the code stripped out:

```
const BluetoothDeviceItem = (Props) => {
    const [connectingState, setConnectingState] = useState(Props.state());
    useEffect(() => {
        stateChangeCallback();
    }, [connectingState]);

    const { onClick } = Props;

    const stateChangeCallback = () => {
        switch (connectingState) {
            case 'not_connected':
                //stuff
                break;
            case 'connecting':
                //stuff
                break;
            case 'connected':
                //stuff
                break;
        }
    }

    const rerender = () => {
        setConnectingState(Props.state());
    }

    const wait = async () => {
        onClick(Props.mac);
        rerender();

    }

    return (
        <IonItem lines="none" class="item-container" id={Props.mac} onClick={wait} ref={Props.elRef}>
            <IonAvatar slot="start" class="bluetooth-icon-container">
                <IonIcon icon={bluetoothOutline} class="bluetooth-icon"></IonIcon>
            </IonAvatar>
            <IonAvatar slot="end" class="connecting-icons-container">
                <IonIcon icon={closeOutline} class="connecting-icons"></IonIcon>
                <IonSpinner name="dots" class="connecting-spinner"></IonSpinner>
            </IonAvatar>
            <IonLabel>
                <div className="device-name">{Props.name}</div>
                <div className="device-mac">{Props.mac}</div>
            </IonLabel>
        </IonItem>
    );
}
export default BluetoothDeviceItem;
```

and here's the Parent (again, cleaned a little bit):

```
const _Bluetooth = () => {

    let states: {} = {}
    const deviceItems: any[] = [];
    const deviceRefs: any[] = [];

    const bluetoothInitialize = () => {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            let a = {name: "test_"+i, mac: i.toString(), connected: false}
            createDeviceItem(a);
        }
    }

    const connect = (id) => {
        deviceItems.forEach(item => { //disconnecting any other currently connected devices and changing their respective states
            if ((item.props.state() === 'connecting' || item.props.state() === 'connected') && item.props.mac !== id) {
                updateDeviceItemState(item.props.mac, 'not_connected');
            }

            if(id === item.props.mac) {
                updateDeviceItemState(item.props.mac, 'connecting');
            }
        });
    }

    const createDeviceItem = (data) => {
        states = {...states, [data.mac]: data.connected ? 'connected' : 'not_connected'}
        let ref = createRef();
        deviceItems.push(<BluetoothDeviceItem elRef={ref} key={data.mac} mac={data.mac} name={data.name} onClick={(id) => connect(id)} state={() => {return states[data.mac]}} elRef={ref}></BluetoothDeviceItem>);
        deviceRefs.push(ref);
    }
    const updateDeviceItemState = (id, connectingState) => {
        states[id] = connectingState;
    }

    return (
        {deviceItems, bluetoothInitialize}
    );
}
export default _Bluetooth;
```

The parent class does a Bluetooth scan (for now just replaced with a for loop). Each time it finds a device it creates a new BluetoothDeviceItem. When you click on one, it's state is set to `not_connected`. At the same time, it checks to see if any other devices are currently `connecting` or `connected`.
Now, setting the device to `connecting` works fine because when you click on it it calls the `wait` function which updates the state of the BluetoothDeviceItem. However, when updating the state of all the other devices (after checking if they are `connected` or `connecting`) because they are not called via the onClick, they don't realise their state was updated. This is why I implemented a `rerender` function which will be called on every BluetoothDeviceItem to make sure they have the latest state.
The issue with this is that I need to lift this function up so the parent class can access it. The most obvious idea would be to use refs. Create a ref, attach to the BluetoothDeviceItem component and get the function. Of course doing that creates the error I said above.
The next best thing is to pass the ref as a props and attach it to the DOM element. Unfortunately this means I am not able to access the functions since they do not exist on the DOM element.
The last thing I tried was using the spread operator (...) to spread the rerender function like so:
`<IonItem lines="none" class="item-container" id={Props.mac} onClick={wait} ref={Props.elRef}> {...rerender}`
so I could access it using the ref. This doesn't work since ...rerender will evaluate to {} (at some point in time I was able to spread a function out but I can't remember how).

How can I lift this rerender function up to the parent *or* update the BluetoothDeviceItem when its state changes?

This is similar to my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs) but I am actually using the answer provided and storing all states in the parent class. I think just due to the nature of how I need these classes and components to work there will always be a need to access something from the child component in the parent class while also having strict restrictions like the child being a function component or the parent not returning JSX

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't really find a simple way of doing it so I ended up just converting the BluetoothDeviceItem function component to a React Component, like so:

```
class BluetoothDeviceItem extends React.Component<Props, {}> {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    private updateIcons = () => {
        switch (this.props.state()) {
            case 'not_connected':
                break;
            case 'connecting':
                break;
            case 'connected':
                break;
        }
    }

    public rerender = () => {
        this.updateIcons();
    }

    private wait = async () => {
        this.props.onClick(this.props.mac);
        this.rerender();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <IonItem lines="none" class="item-container" id={this.props.mac} onClick={this.wait}>
                <IonAvatar slot="start" class="bluetooth-icon-container">
                    <IonIcon icon={bluetoothOutline} class="bluetooth-icon"></IonIcon>
                </IonAvatar>
                <IonAvatar slot="end" class="connecting-icons-container">
                    <IonIcon icon={closeOutline} class="connecting-icons"></IonIcon>
                    <IonSpinner name="dots" class="connecting-spinner"></IonSpinner>
                </IonAvatar>
                <IonLabel>
                    <div className="device-name">{this.props.name}</div>
                    <div className="device-mac">{this.props.mac}</div>
                </IonLabel>
            </IonItem>
        );
    }
}

export default BluetoothDeviceItem;
```

and then just using a ref when I create an instance on that component. That gives me access to the functions I need.