# pass data from child to parent in functional components

Tags: reactjs, callback, react-functional-component

for passing data from parent to child we can pass it as props like :

```
<Child data={data}/>
```

but i would like to send data from child to parent, note that am using functional components, i tried to send a callback function with data parameters as props

IN MY PARENT FUNCTION:

```
   const onSuccess = (data) => {    
    // DO THE FOLLOWING WITH DATA THAT AM TRYING TO GET
  }
 
<Child onSuccess={onSuccess)}/>
```

IN MY CHILD FUNCTION:

```
   const onResponse = (data) => {    
    props.onSuccess(data);
  }
```

so here i want a way to access my parameter data or any other way to get it from a child component, thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: maybe this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs

Comment: thanks, that actually worked!