# How to get data from function component?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I have a function component (A) import another function component (B).

B has a onChange value, I want to get the onChange value all the time when I import B in A.

I have no idea how to get it.

Here is the code like this:

A:

```
import B from './B';

const A = () => {
  // I want to get B's onChange value over here
  return (
    <B />
  );
}
```

B:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const B = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');

  return (
    <SomePicker value={value} onChange={(value) => setValue(value)}
  );
}
```

Comment: Data flow is unidirectional in React. So you cannot use the state from a child component in its parent component.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs
This one answers you question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer below solution.

```
import B from './B';

const A = () => {
 const getOnChangeValueFromB = (data) => {
   console.log(data)// you will get onChange value here
  };   
  // I want to get B's onChange value over here
  return (
    <B callBack={getOnChangeValueFromB}/>
  );
}

import React, { useState } from 'react';

const B = (props) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('');
const returnValueToA = (value) => {
    setValue(value)
    props.callBack(value);

  }
  return (
    <SomePicker value={value} onChange={(value) => returnValueToA(value)}
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer teach me how to get data correctly.

Comment: Cheers!! @Morton