# Pass data from lower to heigher component

Tags: reactjs, pass-data

Here is my hierarchy

```
  - AddEmployee component
  - UpdateComponent
  - Home
      * EmployeeItem component
```

The `the employee item component is just a line in a list` which contains the many columns holding the employees data, among these columns I have the update column which is an icon redirecting to the update component, how can I pass the data of the employee to the `UpdateEmployee component` in order to show them and enable modifying them, I can't use the react router history object, because is undefined in the EmployeeItem component since it's not a route and react-router ignore it.
Is there a way to do it without using readux, or other state manager, I was thinking about `useContext` but it's not clear to me how to do it.

I'm using react-router to handle redirection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Comment: No, it's not from child to parent, see the hierarchy above.

Comment: I believe your problem is simpler that what you're thinking. 

I suggest you read a little about Components and Props in the React documentation.

https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

I'll leave a quick solution here anyways.

Answer (score 0):

To pass data from a parent to a child, just pass it inside the rendering of the component itself. These are called props.

```
<EmployeeItem name = {Lyes} city = {Lisbon}/>
```

Then inside your component

```
const EmployeeItem = props => {
   return (
     <h1>Employee {props.name} is from {props.city}</h1>
   );
}
```