# How can I send data from a child to a parent functional component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a website to convert recipes to a different number of servings. I am using React. I have setup a component to take the number of original servings, new number of servings, and number of ingredients. It will not update in the App.js file when I change the value in the PreInputs component.

App.js:

```
const App = () => {
  //define variables using states
  const [numIngredients, setNumIngredients] = useState(5);
  const [originalServings, setOriginalServings] = useState(8);
  const [newServings, setNewServings] = useState(4);
  
  //create handling functions for the variables
  const handleNumIngredients = (num) => {
    setNumIngredients(num);
  }

  const handleOriginalServings = (num) => {
    setOriginalServings(num)
  }

  const handleNewServings = (num) => {
    setNewServings(num);
  }

  
  return (
  <div>
    <Header title="test"/>
    <PreInputs changeNumIngredients={handleNumIngredients} changeOriginalServings={handleOriginalServings} changeNewServings={handleNewServings}/>
    <h1>{originalServings}</h1>
  </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

PreInputs.js:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from 'react';

export const PreInputs = (props) => {
    const numOriginalServings = useState(0)

    const handleOriginalServingsChange = (e) => {
        const originalServings = e.target.value;
        props.changeOriginalServings(originalServings)
    }
    
    return (
        <div className='pre-inputs'>
            <form>
                <label>Original Servings: </label>
                <input value={numOriginalServings} onChange={handleOriginalServingsChange} type='number' />
                <button></button>
            </form>
            <h1>Placeholder</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: The `useState` hook use isn't correct in the `PreInputs` child component, you should array destructure assign the state and updater function. You also only consume the `changeOriginalServings` prop, did you need to use the other two that were passed?

Comment: @DrewReese Thank you, I am new to React. Could you point more towards the correct Syntax for that?

Comment: It will look suspiciously similar to the `useState` usage in the parent `App` component, but check the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate). [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) also explains the pattern you are trying to use, passing a callback to a child component to update state in a parent. Can you also clarify more what isn't updating in the parent component?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is anti-pattern in React to store passed props into local state, so you don't really need the `numOriginalServings` state in `PreInputs`. Pass `originalServings` to `PreInputs` to be used as the default value of the input and pass the updated input value back to the parent component.

PreInputs

```
const PreInputs = (props) => {
  const handleOriginalServingsChange = (e) => {
    const originalServings = e.target.value;
    props.changeOriginalServings(originalServings);
  };

  return (
    <div className="pre-inputs">
      <form>
        <label>Original Servings: </label>
        <input
          defaultValue={props.originalServings} // <-- initialize input
          onChange={handleOriginalServingsChange}
          type="number"
        />
      </form>
      <h1>Placeholder</h1>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Parent

```
function App() {
  //define variables using states
  const [numIngredients, setNumIngredients] = useState(5);
  const [originalServings, setOriginalServings] = useState(8);
  const [newServings, setNewServings] = useState(4);

  //create handling functions for the variables
  const handleNumIngredients = (num) => {
    setNumIngredients(num);
  };

  const handleOriginalServings = (num) => {
    setOriginalServings(num);
  };

  const handleNewServings = (num) => {
    setNewServings(num);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Header title="test"/>
      <h1>{originalServings}</h1>
      <PreInputs
        originalServings={originalServings} // <-- pass state
        changeOriginalServings={handleOriginalServings} // <-- pass callback
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-send-data-from-a-child-to-a-parent-functional-component-in-reactjs]

Answer (score 0):

if you want to send data to the parent component

you have 3 ways for it

```
1- use redux

2- use context

3- make function in the parent component and get data in this function and sent function to the child component
```

Answer (score 0):

According to good programming practice, you shouldn't transfer state this way.
For small Apps you should use [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

It's really simple and superfast, especially for data reads.