# How can I pass fetched data between components?

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I am fetching some data in my App component and mapping through it to display names. I also have a counter component which besides the counts, I want to render the user names from the data fetched in App. I wish to know how do I pass the data's user names as props to the counter component so that it displays the names there as well?

Here is my App:

```
function App() {
  const {data, isLoading} = useAsync({promiseFn: loadUsers})
  if (isLoading)
    return "Loading..."
  if (data)

    return (<div className="container">
      {
        data.map(user => (
          <div key={user.username} className="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h2>{user.name}</h2>  // Need this to also display in button component
                <Counter id={user.name}/>
              </div>
```

My Counter Component's return :

```
  return (
    <div>
      <b>Would you like to work with (user.name data from app) </b> &nbsp; <i onClick={handleIncrement} class="far fa-thumbs-up" style={clickStyle}> Yes!</i>
      <br/>
      <h><b>{count}</b> have said Yes!</h>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: <Counter user={user}/>

Comment: Have you read react's tutorial https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html? I could give you straight answer, but seriously, read their docu.

Comment: You already pass `user.name` as the `id` prop, so.... access `props.id`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Comment: Syntax wise I am not getting it. The App is my parent component, so I should be passing from parent to child

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `App` component you're sending the user's name as id into `Counter`.When you're sending a variable from parent component into another one, you can access it via `props` in child component. Also you need to pass props into child components. In addition You should change the `user.name` to `props.id`. Based on your code which you have attached in `stackbiltz`. Here's the correct code:

```
function Likes(props) {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const KEY = `count-${props.id}`;
  const clickStyle = {
    color: '#2197ba',
    cursor: 'pointer'
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const parsedCount = Number(localStorage.getItem(KEY) || 0);
    setCount(parsedCount);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(KEY, count);
  }, [count]);

  const handleIncrement = () => {
    setCount(prevCount => prevCount + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <b>Would you like to work with counter {props.id} </b> &nbsp;{' '}
      <i onClick={handleIncrement} class="far fa-thumbs-up" style={clickStyle}>
        {' '}
        Yes!
      </i>
      <br />
      <h>
        <b>{count}</b> have said Yes!
      </h>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Please refer to this document for more information about props: https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Could you take a look at this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bfrfxa?file=src%2FApp.js The Counter id set to user name is for each counter to have a unique value.

Comment: @JabbatheHutt Updated the code. Please see this link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b8reny?file=src%2Fcomponents%2FCounter.js

Comment: Oh I see. I didn't set props on top. Thanks

Comment: @JabbatheHutt your welcome. Did your problem solve?

Answer (score 0):

You can also destructure your `props` inside Counter component, so that you don't need to write `props.id`.

```
function Counter({id}) {  //here I destructured it
      return (
        <div>
          <b>Would you like to work with {id} data from app </b> &nbsp; <i onClick={handleIncrement} class="far fa-thumbs-up" style={clickStyle}> Yes!</i>
          <br/>
          <h><b>{count}</b> have said Yes!</h>
        </div>
      );
    }
```