# Pass onFocus from react component

Tags: reactjs, next.js, components

I want to hide the yellow title when focus on input
but I cant pass it from the component to use it in index page
https://codesandbox.io/s/focus-insi7

Comment: You cannot pass props from child component to parent in react

Comment: Does this answer your question: [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60315004/1870780)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using plain CSS.

For example, if you have something like this:

```
<div>
  <input />
  <span/>
</div>
```

and wanted to affect the `span` element when the `input` is focussed, you can do:

```
input:focus + span {
  // Whatever styles you want to be applied to the span
}
```