# How to send data created in child to parent using react hook?

Tags: reactjs, echarts

As the question state, what I am trying to do is pass a child value from child to parent. I want to call the child variable in my parent function.

Parent code

```
function App() {

  let [value, setVal] = useState(null);
  ...
  const onLayoutChange = (layout) => {
    console.log(value);
    if (value != null) {
      value.resize();
    }
    //   chartInstance.resize();
  };

  return (
    <ResponsiveGridLayout
      layouts={layout}
      onLayoutChange={() => onLayoutChange(layout)}
    >
      <div key="1">
        <Card style={styles} val={setVal} />
      </div>
    </ResponsiveGridLayout>
  );
}
```

#1 child code

```
export default function SimpleCard(props) {
 
  return (
    <Card style={props.style.main}>
      <CardContent>
        <NewvsReturnVisitors value={props.val} />
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
}
```

#2 child code

```
const Newvsresturnvisitors = (props) => {
  ...
  let [val, setVal] = useState(null);

  let chartInstance = null;
  props.value(val);

  function renderChart() {
    const renderInstance = echarts.getInstanceByDom(chart.current);

    if (renderInstance) {
      chartInstance = renderInstance;
      setVal(chartInstance);
    } else {
      chartInstance = echarts.init(chart.current, null, {
        width: 500,
        height: 300
      });

      setVal(chartInstance);
      // chartInstance.resize();
    }
    chartInstance.setOption(option);
  }
  ...
}
export default Newvsresturnvisitors;
```

I am not sure if this is possible, any advice is really appreciated.

This is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-grid-layout-with-resizable-forked-pq7ku?file=/src/newvsreturnvisitors.js:590-603) to my codesandbox

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a state variable in the parent component, and then pass the setXXX method to the child component, in the child component call the setXXX method to pass the variable to the parent.

Comment: i have edit my question, so i have tried ur method, but now i have a new warning.  `Warning: Cannot update a component (App) while rendering..`  same link, open console and the warning is there

Comment: You may try to move
console.log(value);

out of the  onLayoutChange function.

Comment: I have edit my question , so i encapsulate the value with a if condition and my the resize function is not executed :(

Answer (score 0):

```
const changeLayout = (layout) => {
    //   chartInstance.resize();
  };


<ResponsiveGridLayout
      layouts={layout}
      onLayoutChange={changeLayout}
    >
```

try to use props li like this