# Passing Value to parent in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

To-Do List

I have a parent with a `useState` called tasks (array).
And for each of those items (task) in the array, I am displaying a component with the item data and a delete button.

Now each component(child) has a delete button. But the array with the tasks is in the parent class so I can't delete the task or that component as the button is inside the component (child).

Any solutions for this problem?

**Note**: I have tried to find a solution but I can't seem to find it. SO just tell me what to do, the whole code is here.

> The parts that need help are commented

Parent:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  Keyboard,
  KeyboardAvoidingView,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
} from "react-native";
import Task from "./components/Task";

export default function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]);
  const [newTask, setNewTask] = useState();

  const AddTask = () => {
    Keyboard.dismiss();
    if (newTask == null) return;
    setTasks([...tasks, { name: newTask }]);
    setNewTask(null);
  };

  const removeTodo = (index) => {
    let CopyLi = [...tasks];
    CopyLi.splice(index, 1);
    setTasks(CopyLi);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.taskWrapper}>
        <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>Today's task</Text>

        <ScrollView style={styles.items}>

          {/* Here is the Rendering of Child Component */}

          {tasks.map((item, index) => {
            return <Task key={index} text={item.name} />;
          })}
        </ScrollView>
      </View>

      <KeyboardAvoidingView
        behavior={Platform.OS === "ios" ? "padding" : "height"}
        style={styles.inputWrapper}
      >
        <TextInput
          style={styles.input}
          placeholder={"Add a new Task"}
          value={newTask}
          onChangeText={(text) => setNewTask(text)}
        />

        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => AddTask()}>
          <View style={styles.btnWrapper}>
            <Text style={styles.btnIcon}>+</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#e8eaed",
  },
  taskWrapper: {
    paddingTop: 80,
  },
  sectionTitle: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: "bold",
    marginHorizontal: 20,
  },
  items: {
    marginTop: 30,
    height: "78%",
  },
  inputWrapper: {
    width: "100%",
    flexDirection: "row",
    justifyContent: "space-around",
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 100,
  },
  input: {
    paddingVertical: 15,
    paddingHorizontal: 20,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 60,
    borderColor: "#C0C0C0",
    borderWidth: 1,
    width: "70%",
  },
  btnWrapper: {
    width: 60,
    height: 60,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 60,
    borderColor: "#C0C0C0",
    borderWidth: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  btnIcon: {
    fontSize: 30,
    transform: [{ translateY: -2 }],
    color: "#A4A4A4",
  },
});
```

Child:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  CheckBox,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from "react-native";

const Task = (props) => {
  const [toggle, setToggle] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View style={styles.item}>
      <View style={styles.itemLeft}>
        <CheckBox
          value={toggle}
          onValueChange={setToggle}
          style={[{ textDecorationLine: "line-through" }, styles.square]}
        />
        <Text
          style={[styles.itemText, toggle ? styles.checked : styles.unchecked]}
        >
          {props.text}
        </Text>
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity style={styles.itemRight}></TouchableOpacity>

      {/*Here is the Button/TouchableOpacity to delete this component */}

    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  item: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    padding: 15,
    borderRadius: 10,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginBottom: 20,
    width: "90%",
    alignSelf: "center",
  },
  itemLeft: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
  square: {
    marginRight: 10,
    transform: [{ scaleX: 1.2 }, { scaleY: 1.2 }],
  },
  itemText: {
    maxWidth: "80%",
    fontSize: 16,
  },
  checked: { textDecorationLine: "line-through" },
  unchecked: { textDecorationLine: "none" },
  itemRight: {
    width: 15,
    height: 15,
    borderColor: "#f94355",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "#ff2848",
  },
});

export default Task;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in Parent component create remove function, and passed to child component, then use remove function in child component and pass index. For example, your code look like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

function Todo({ todo, index, removeTodo }) {
    return (
        <div className="todo">
            <span>{todo.text}</span>
            <button onClick={() => removeTodo(index)}>Delete</button>
        </div>
    );
};

function App() {
    const [todos, setTodos] = React.useState([
        { text: "Learn about React" },
        { text: "Meet friend for lunch" },
        { text: "Build really cool todo app" }
    ]);

    const removeTodo = (index) => {

        let todosArrCopy = [...todos];

        todosArrCopy.splice(index,1);

        setTodos(todosArrCopy);
    }

    return (
        <div className="app">
            <div className="todo-list">
                {todos.map((todo, index) => (
                    <Todo
                        key={index}
                        index={index}
                        todo={todo}
                        removeTodo={removeTodo}
                    />
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>  
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must declare the method called by the child component delete button in the parent, and pass it to the child component as a prop. The main app.js file should be something like:

```
import './App.css';
import ChildComponent from './ChildComponent';
import { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {
  const [todoList, setTodoList] = useState(["task 0","task 1","task 2","task 3","task 4"])
  
  const deleteTask = (tobedeleted) => {
    let todos = todoList;
    setTodoList(todos.filter((todo) => {return todo !== tobedeleted}))

}
  
return (
    <div className="App">
      <ul>
        {todoList.map(
          function(todo, idx) {
            return (<li key={idx}>{todo} <ChildComponent handleDelete={() => deleteTask(todo)} /></li>)
          }
        )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

While your child component would be:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <button  
            onClick={props.handleDelete}
        >
            Delete Task
        </button>
    );
}

export default ChildComponent;
```

Comment: A good attempt but its not working. The function got called as soon as the component is made.

Comment: You are right! I modified the code in order to make it run correctly. Basically I was passing the return value of the deleteTask function to the child component and not its reference!

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally you would pass the function into the child component as a prop on the child.

However, you need to consider the implications of the deletion and how it impacts other items in the list. In order to stop unnecessary re-renders of your child tasks whenever a task is deleted, you need to introduce [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) and [React.memo](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo).

> React.memo is a higher order component.
>
> If your component renders the same result given the same props, you
> can wrap it in a call to React.memo for a performance boost in some
> cases by memoizing the result. This means that React will skip
> rendering the component, and reuse the last rendered result.

> useCallback returns a memoized callback.
>
> Pass an inline callback and an array of dependencies. useCallback will
> return a memoized version of the callback that only changes if one of
> the dependencies has changed. This is useful when passing callbacks to
> optimized child components that rely on reference equality to prevent
> unnecessary renders (e.g. shouldComponentUpdate).

Without these, you will be passing in a **new** function to the child every time state changes in your parent and this will result in **all** the children rendering again. This may be undesirable with larger lists.

Demo:

```js
const {
  useState,
  memo,
  useCallback
} = React;

// we use memo here to return a optimized version of our higher order component. 
// We compare the task values between renders to determine if we should render again.
const Task = memo(({task, deleteTask}) => {
  const handleClick = (e) => {
    const {value} = e.currentTarget;
    deleteTask(value);
  }
  
  return ( 
    <button value={task} onClick={handleClick}>{task} <br/>({Date.now()})</button>
  )
}, (prevProps, nextProps) => prevProps.task.toUpperCase() === nextProps.task.toUpperCase());

// dummy data
const data = Array(20).fill(null).map((i, index) => `task ${(index + 1).toString()}`);

function App() {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState(data);
  
  // wrap the function in useCallback to memoized version of the callback
  const deleteTask = useCallback((task) => {
    setTasks(prevState => prevState.filter((x) => x !== task));
  }, [setTasks]);

  return ( 
    <div> 
      {tasks.map((task) => (
        <Task key={task} task={task} deleteTask={deleteTask} />
      ))} 
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render( <
  App / > ,
  document.getElementById("app")
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```