# React MUI Autocomplete - managing onChange event from the parent component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My goal is to trigger a custom function by the **onChange** event belonging to the child component, from the parent component.
In my case the child component is the React MUI Autocomplete component.

Considering the example about the *Controllable States* from the [documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-autocomplete/#controlled-states):

```
import * as React from 'react';
import TextField from '@mui/material/TextField';
import Autocomplete from '@mui/material/Autocomplete';

const options = ['Option 1', 'Option 2'];

export default function ControllableStates() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState(options[0]);
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{`value: ${value !== null ? `'${value}'` : 'null'}`}</div>
      <div>{`inputValue: '${inputValue}'`}</div>
      <br />
      <Autocomplete
        value={value}
        onChange={(event, newValue) => {
          setValue(newValue);
        }}
        inputValue={inputValue}
        onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
          setInputValue(newInputValue);
        }}
        id="controllable-states-demo"
        options={options}
        sx={{ width: 300 }}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Controllable" />}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit ControllableStates Material Demo]

as you can see, the onChange event is already defined to update the new value. Ok.

Usually, what I do to manipulate this event from the parent component is simply:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import { StyledEngineProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
import Demo from './demo';

function handleChange(event)
{
  console.log("Hello!")
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#root")).render(
  <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
    <Demo onChange={handleChange} />
  </StyledEngineProvider>
);
```

But in this case it doesn't work, probably because onChange is "already taken" by the Autocomplete component.

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0):

For those who will face the same problem:

I don't know if there is a way to use onChange directly from the parent component, but I solved the problem with a [different approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60315004).