# How to pass ref from child to parent with nested components?

Tags: reactjs

How to pass ref from child to parent through several nested components?
`forwardRef` working only for directly child to parent way

Child:

```
const Menu = forwardRef((props, menuRef) => { 
  return <div ref={menuRef}></div>
}
```

Parent:

```
const Header = () => {
  const menuRef = useRef(null)
  return {<Menu ref={menuRef}/>}
}
```

Parent of the parent:

```
const Layout = () => {
```

...here I want ref from child

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Please add the code that you have tried?

Comment: did you try to pass via `useContext()`?

Comment: I want to render part of the menu from the header on the page

Comment: Reasons for doing this are often faulty. Data down, events up. You might explain your situation better so we can provide the best solution.

Comment: Also, this has been discussed at length already. [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38394015/1264804)

Comment: Ok, I think it will be easier to render the menu 2 times