# React - change value of parent variable from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web-deployment

I know this could be a noob question but I'm learning React for a few months and now I'm stucked with this problem. I got this code over here:

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react'
import ReactTags from 'react-tag-autocomplete'

const TagsHandler = ({ tagPlaceholder, suggestions }) => {
  const [tags, setTags] = useState([])
  const reactTags = useRef()

  const onDelete = useCallback(
    (tagIndex) => {
      setTags(tags.filter((_, i) => i !== tagIndex))
    },
    [tags]
  )

  const onAddition = useCallback(
    (newTag) => {
      setTags([...tags, newTag])
    },
    [tags]
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    suggestions.map((suggestion) => {
      suggestion.disabled = tags.some((tag) => tag.id === suggestion.id)
    })
  }, [tags])

  return (
    <ReactTags
      ref={reactTags}
      tags={tags}
      suggestions={suggestions}
      onDelete={onDelete}
      onAddition={onAddition}
      placeholderText={tagPlaceholder}
    />
  )
}

export default TagsHandler
```

Which implements a tag list inside my parent component. This parent component has a bool value which enables a save button. I should enable this button whenever a user adds or removes a tag to the list. My question is: how can I handle this bool from the child component? I've read about Redux but I'd like to avoid using it. I was thinking about a SetState function or a callback but I can't figure out the syntax.
Any help would be really appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: you can have the `state` in parent component, and pass the `state`, `setter` reference to the child and then set using setter passed from parent in child ....

Comment: That's wierd. You already know how to pass a function from parent to a child. Why not do the same thing in a high level of components.

Comment: @KcH passing `setter` gives you far less flexibility then passing custom callback function every time you use the component

Comment: @deaponn, yeah but that's okay for a simple e.g.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass data from child component to its parent in ReactJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394015/how-to-pass-data-from-child-component-to-its-parent-in-reactjs)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply create a function in your parent component: toggleButton, and pass the function to your child component.

```
function Parent = (props) => {
    const [isToggle, setIsToggle] = useState(false);

    const toggleButton = () => {
          setIsToggle(!isToggle)
    }

    return <Child toggled={isToggle} toggle={toggleButton} />
}
```

Comment: This is not a toggle function as it only sets your boolean to `true` instead of toggling it.

Comment: yeah, it's not toggle

Comment: @RoyChristo, we didn't mean to change the naming , you have to do state set as `setIsToggle( prev => !prev)` so it checks previous state and inverts it (which would be toggle) ... hope it makes sense

Comment: HaHa... my bad again. updated

Comment: Thanks for your answer :
I already have a structure like this in my parent component: `const [isTouched, setTouched] = useState(false)`
Shouldn't I call the toggle prop anywhere in my child component?

Comment: If you pass it to your child. Yes

Comment: Ok, so I'd like to call it inside my UseEffect so everytime my tags array is updated I can enable the save button. Let's suppose I've got something like this: `const TagsHandler = ({ tagPlaceholder, suggestions, setBool })`
How should I modify my UseEffect function?

Comment: some thing like this `useEffect(() => {
  if(isArrayUpdated){
     setBool()
 }
})`

Comment: I've modified my child like this: `useEffect(()=>{setBool()}`. Inside my parent I got `const toggleButton=()=>{setTouched(true)}` and then `return <TagsHandler setBool={toggleButton}`. Btw now the save button is enabled at the begging of the application and that's because toggleButton gets called by default I guess. How can I make my code calls toggleButton only when the useEffect of the child is triggered?

Comment: `useEffect(() => {
    suggestions.map((suggestion) => {
      suggestion.disabled = tags.some((tag) => tag.id === suggestion.id)
    });
   setBool();
  }, [tags])`

Answer (score 0):

So the general approach is as follows:
In the `Parent.jsx`:

```
const [childrenActive, setChildrenActive] = useState(false)

// later in the render function
<Children setIsActive={(newActive) => setChildrenActive(newActive)} />
```

In the `Children.jsx`:

```
const Children = ({ setIsActive }) => {
    return <button onClick={() => setIsActive(true)}>Click me</button>
}
```

So, as you have guessed, we pass a callback function. I would avoid passing `setState` directly because it makes your component less flexible.

Comment: I guess it should be `<Children setIsActive={(newActive) => setChildrenActive(!newActive)} />` ...

Comment: @KcH no, as it would make input reversed. This is a callback function and when you pass `true` to it, it would set negated, `false`, to the `setState`

Comment: That's what buddy you missed `!newActive` which I added 

Comment: And then when OP calls `setIsActive(true)` from children, `childrenActive` will be set to `false` in parent because it got negated. This is not the desired behavior as we wanted to set this boolean `true` in the first place.

Comment: I didn't miss that, it's just setting directly what needs to be set. If you wanted to make a toggle mutation, you would do `setChildrenActive(current => !current)` in the parent component.

Comment: hmm, so it shouldn't be called "toggle" tbh

Comment: @KcH I didn't use word toggle once in my answer, nor did OP use it in his question.

Comment: haha my bad ... seeing the answer voted above and the comments I have thought it ... nvm :)

Answer (score 0):

In the parent component, the function that is responsible for changing that bool variable, you pass as a prop to the child component. At the child component you get that props and you can update if you want.